# Swap every two elements in a list

Tags: code-golf, array

### Challenge

Let's have a list `L` of `n` elements. The task is to swap every two elements in this list.

### Constrains

- the list `L` has at least two elements
- size of the list `L` is a multiple of two (i.e. number of elements is even)

#### Example

- input: `[1,2,3,4,5,6]`
- output: `[2,1,4,3,6,5]`
- input: `[0,1,0,1]`
- output: `[1,0,1,0]`

### Rules

- this is `code-golf` challenge, so the shortest code wins
- [standard rules apply](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/default-for-code-golf-program-function-or-snippet/2422#2422) for your answer with [default I/O rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods/), so you are allowed to use stdin/stdout, functions/method with the proper parameters and return-type, full programs
- [default Loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden.

Comment: [Welcome to Code Golf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20861/welcome-to-code-golf-and-coding-challenges-stack-exchange) and nice first question! For future reference, we recommend using the [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges) to get feedback on challenge ideas before posting them to main

Comment: What types of elements must the list support? In particular, is it all right if a solution only works on lists of non-negative/unsigned integers?

Comment: Yes, that's fine

Comment: Can we use a `char[]` array in a language like C? If so, there is a certain built-in that would make the answer very short (`s***`).

Comment: Sure, go ahead. However, I'd say that if there are two solutions with the same length, then the more general one wins (the one that works for more inputs/datatypes).

Answer (score 21):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), <s>4</s> 3 bytes

```
i#o
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/PzMzP///f0MjYxNTMwA)

Lol, ><> <s>ties with</s> beats Jelly & 05AB1E. Terminates with an error.

-1 thanks to @Manny Queen.

## How does it work?

```
     The instruction pointer (IP) is currently moving right
i    Take input as a character
 #   Reflect - The IP starts moving left
i    Take input again
  o  Output that
 #   Reflect - The IP starts moving right again
  o  Output the first input we took - the inputs are now swapped

And now, we're moving left and back at the start again on i + moving right. 
This loops forever (i.e. until erroring when we're out of input) 
because there is no halt instruction (;)
This is essentially executing "iioo" in an infinite loop.
```

Comment: no longer beats Vyxal

Comment: @wasif Oh well, still beats Jelly and osabie.

Answer (score 13):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `r`, 2 bytes

```
yY
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=r&code=yY&inputs=%5B1%2C2%2C3%2C4%2C5%2C6%5D&header=&footer=)

Explanation:

```
y  # Uninterleave
 Y # Interleave
```

Comment: What does the r flag do?

Comment: @ZippyMagician The `r` flag makes all commands take their arguments in reverse order. That doesn't affect `y` since it only has one argument, but it does affect `Y`, meaning that the program is essentially equivalent to `y$Y`, which swaps the halves before interleaving.

Answer (score 12):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 34 bytes

```python
f=lambda l:l and l[1::-1]+f(l[2:])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P802JzE3KSVRIccqRyExL0UhJ9rQykrXMFY7TSMn2sgqVvN/QVFmXolGmka0oY6RjrGOiY6pjlmspuZ/AA)

When `l` is empty (which makes it falsy), return it directly. Otherwise, reverse the first two elements and make a recursive call for the rest.

Answer (score 12):

## [convey](http://xn--wxa.land/convey/), 7 bytes

I knew I should have implemented SpaceChem's flipflop operator, then this would be 5 bytes. :-)

*-6 byte by @Manny Queen*

```
}?{
}~1
```

[Try it online!](https://xn--wxa.land/convey/run.html#eyJjIjoifT97XG59fjEiLCJ2IjoxLCJpIjoiMSAyIDMgNCA1IDYifQ==)

`{` puts the input list on the conveyor, `}` prints the result. On the `?` the elements try to go down if they can. On the `~` they will wait for `1` tick before going to the output, thus starting with the first item, every second element is delayed for two ticks.

#### 13 bytes

```
},<
{@^
0"
1^
```

[Try it online!](https://xn--wxa.land/convey/run.html#eyJjIjoifSw8XG57QF5cbjBcIlxuMV4iLCJ2IjoxLCJpIjoiMSAyIDMgNCA1IDYifQ==)

The lower loop `0"\1^` copies `0 1 0 1 …` into choose `@`. The input is thus split into two paths. The right one takes a little bit longer, so the other number can overtake it before joining `,` again.

[image: variant 2 with input 1 to 6]

Comment: [The second one can be made shorter with some rearrangement.](https://xn--wxa.land/convey/run.html#eyJjIjoidjw/e1xuLDx+MVxufSIsInYiOjEsImkiOiIxIDIgMyA0IDUgNiJ9)

Comment: This makes me want to learn convey. It looks awesome.

Comment: @MannyQueen, m90 thanks! Multiple outputs are well defined when they don't fire at the same step, so this is a very neat solution!

Answer (score 12):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 22 bytes

```hs
f(a:b:c)=b:a:f c
f x=x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P00j0SrJKlnTNskq0SpNIZkrTaHCtuJ/bmJmnoKtQkq@ApdCQVFmXomCikJatKGenlksioCOgQ4Ux/4HAA)

Comment: `f=concatMap(reverse.take 2).iterate(drop 2)`

Comment: @Roman Czyborra nice but there's nothing stopping iterate.. [that way](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P802OT8vObHEN7FAoyi1LLWoOFWvJDE7VcFIE0yHZ2TmpGro20bHaupllqQWJZakaqQU5RcA5f/nJmbmKdgqpOQrcCkUFGXmlSioKKRFG@rpmcWiCOgY6EAxqnjsfwA "Haskell – Try It Online") works fine

Answer (score 11):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 9 bytes

```
,[>,.<.,]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fJ9pOR89GTyf2/39DI2MTUzMA)

Answer (score 10):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/) v1.37.0, <s>59</s> <s>55</s> 47 bytes

```rust
|a:&[_]|(0..).zip(a).map(|i|a[i.0^1]).collect()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Lc1NDoIwFATgtZ7iyYK0ybPhR12g4C3cEDQNwaRJKQ2UmEg5e63AajbfzPTjYNxbQcuFIhSm/U42BoYP10PuLM/C8lVZEjFG2VdowilruSZWWF4KFj3jirK6k7KpDaHuuraF0qOBHMoYIUFIEU4IZ4RLtYFuNF5k8Gjqm0iTwtvlkYRLlXqme6GMVAcSTNl9hmMB/wxwHcdtwsvZ/QA)

*-2 bytes thanks to ZippyMagician*
*-2 bytes thanks to alephalpha*
*-8 bytes thanks to `(0..).zip(a)`*

Rust is not a golfy language...
Port of the [C#](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/237101/44998) and [JS](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/237108/44998) answers
v1.37.0 is the version available on TIO

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/) stable, 54 bytes

```rust
|a:&[_]|a.chunks(2).flat_map(|a|[a[1],a[0]]).collect()
```

[Try it online!](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=303e751fa22451f42bc9f876119481cd)

Thanks to ZippyMagician for this *slightly* golfier answer on the latest version of Rust.

Comment: If you don’t use tio's outdated version of rust, `|a:&[i32]|a.chunks(2).flat_map(|a|[a[1],a[0]]).collect()` is 3 bytes shorter

Comment: If you do, [57 bytes](https://tio.run/##LY3LDoIwFETX@hVXFqRNaiP4WKDgX7ghmDSkJk1KIeU2LijfXiuwmlmcOWPdiOFjoBPKEArTfqclwvgVw1gGL4q0Vue88YIrlJZQLo3rpBUoY@/EQLzyolb89M4ayttea9kioeG@epQZHEIJdcYgZ3BmcGFwZXBrNqB3GIkCXrJ9xKMqsss3SZcpjdhglUFtDiSZiucMxwr@mbBVzjZFJOfwAw "Rust – Try It Online")

Comment: I think you can use `&[_]` instead of `&[i32]`.

Comment: @ZippyMagician I managed to outgolf your stable rust answer with TIO's outdated version of rust :P

Answer (score 9):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 30 bytes

```python
def f(a,b,*m):print b,a,;f(*m)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYs7DsMgEAV7TrElWK8IzqcgtW@QznJhJ4uMlGCENrI5PUEpphnNpCLrFvtaX@zJ6xkLuo9xKYcotGDG3esm6r6GN5N1iiQX18ouxPQVbYwiPp6chB4l8ZDzlh399zpa9DjjgitukxpPsGhMPw)

The function `f` takes input splatted like `f(1,2,3,4,5,6)`, and prints the output space-separated, terminating with error.

---

**34 bytes**

```python
lambda l:map(l.pop,len(l)/2*[1,0])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcpLCoAgEADQfadwqTGU2mchdJJyYVQojDaEEZ3eWr9Hb/Zn0uWYloIurptjaKIjjg2dBLgnjqLV9axAWlEeH3BnytAVUmYHD4nuzIUov2vooIcBRlvNEv4Pyn4)

This works by alternating popping the elements at index `1` and index `0`.

Answer (score 7):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 22 bytes

```
0<##<1||#2&&#&&#0@##3&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b738BGWdnGsKZG2UhNTRmIDByUlY3V/geWZqaWOAQUZeaVRCvr2qU5OCjHqtUFJyfm1VVzVRvqGOkY65jomOqY1epwVRvoGOoAMYRpUMtV@x8A)

Input `[L...]`, and returns in an `And`. Works on integer inputs.

---

#### [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 24 bytes

```
{}=={##}||#2&&#&&#0@##3&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b7v7rW1rZaWbm2pkbZSE1NGYgMHJSVjdX@B5ZmppY4BBRl5pVEK@vapTk4KMeq1QUnJ@bVVXNVG@oY6RjrmOiY6pjV6nBVG@gY6gAxhGlQy1X7HwA)

Input `[L...]`, and returns in an `And`. Works on non-boolean inputs.

#### [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 26 bytes

```
#2~##&~#&@@@#~Partition~2&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcM7CoAwDADQvdcIdIqg9bMpOULBURxCUexgBclWmqtXH7yb5Tpulhi4nnMFpwBWwRIRqOdXosQnqbPVvzHJBs1yEuxW18BJs8kdOuxxwBGngia32OG/mFI/)

Input `[L]`, and returns a list. Works.

Comment: `#~Partition~2~Reverse~2&` is –2 bytes, if the OP doesn't mind the extra braces in the output:   `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}`  ⟹ `{{2, 1}, {4, 3}, {6, 5}}`

Comment: @theorist IMO, that doesn't output what the specs ask for - it outputs a list of pairs.

Comment: Yeah, figured you'd say that :).  Could you save anything using `BlockMap` instead of `Partition`?  E.g., `BlockMap[Reverse,#,2]&` is 2 bytes shorter than `#~Partition~2~Reverse~2&`.  And how would you implement your function in the MMA front end? E.g., `list={1,2,3,4,5,6}` `#2~##&~#&@@@#~Partition~2&@list` doesn't work.

Comment: @theorist I initially thought about `BlockMap`, but arguments to the function are provided as a list, so `...@@#` is required, making `Partition` with `@@@` shorter. Use `##&[#2,#]&` instead; I'm not sure why infix `##&` is recognized in wolframscript but not in a notebook.

Answer (score 6):

## JavaScript (ES6), 23 bytes

```
x=>x.map((_,i)=>x[i^1])
```

The `[i^1]` is thanks to m90 in TNB

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z@TWqJQXJ5YUGz7P9HWLlEvN7FAQyNeJ1MTyInOjDOM1QQrycwrKC1RsFWINtQx0jHWMdEx1TGLteZKzs8rzs9J1cvJT9dIUKkGq6pV0LVTUKkGG6oBFtGsTdC0/g8A)

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 36 bytes

```python
lambda a:sum(zip(a[1::2],a[::2]),())
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUSHRqrg0V6Mqs0AjMdrQysooVicxGkRp6mhoav4vKMrMK9FI04g21DHSMdYx0THVMYsFigMA)

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/) + numpy, 31 bytes

```python
lambda m:m[~-(m==m).cumsum()^1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XcqxDoIwEADQna/oeJecREQdNP0SwOTAEEm841LaoQu/Xp0Z3vYsx8@qbZl9X74s45udPKTbTyDeC9ZTki0J4KsZyiK2hug0iWXHm1OrKvZqNYfAGbqGLtTSlW50H/BpYdEITDMw4uGd6e94yg8)

Expects a numpy array. Most of the code is about avoiding referencing numpy directly, so we can avoid the explicit import. It then calculates the indices directly by xoring a counter with 1.

Comment: `(m*0).argsort()` should work for -2.

Comment: @ovs, only up to len(m)==16. From 17 numpy uses an unstable sort algorithm by default. https://tio.run/##DcoxDoAgDADAnVd0bB1MjIvxNwyADLRNwQE/X7n5dI5H@HTPJg34bTqhNhUbW8hiwFAZLHJJeFx0B1jUKg/8kklHpj1a6esjkfsP

Answer (score 5):

## [Ly](https://github.com/LyricLy/Ly), 7 bytes

```
ir[foo]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y6n8/z@zKDotPz/2/39DI2MTUzNzCwA)

Pretty straightforward, but might be worth posting since it's almost pronounceable. :)

```
ir       -- read input codepoints into the stack, reverse the order
  [   ]  -- while the stack isn't empty
   foo   -- flip the top two entries and print as characters
```

## [Cubix](https://github.com/ETHproductions/cubix), 14 bytes

```
..@.i?i.o;o;.^
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy5Nyqz4/19Pz0Ev0z5TL98631ov7v9/QyNjE1MzcwsA)

This is the first time I've tried to use Cubix, so I wouldn't be suprised if it's possible to do this with less code.  It's a hard language to explain, since it's a 2D language where the code is wrapped around a cube.  So the directions the instruction pointer take a hard to show in a description.  I'll include a link to the online interpreter since it has a debug mode when you can see the way the code iterates through the cells.

But I'll try to explain it too...

```
..@.i?i.o;o;.^ - code before it's wrapped on the cube...
    i          - (1) starts here, input a codepoint
     ?         - branch if top of stack, <0 "left", >0 "right"
  @            - "left" (true on EOF), halt program
             ^ - "right", set IP direction to "up"
     ?         - same branch, but coming from another direction
      i        - "right", input another codepoint
        o;     - output top of stack as char, pop it off stack
          o;   - repeat... code wraps back to (1)
```

The `.` characters are no-ops and are needed to place the other characters in the right position so they will wrap into place on the cube.

Here's a link to the online interpreter
http://ethproductions.github.io/cubix/?code=Li5ALmk/aS5vO287Ll4=&input=MTIzNDU2Nzg=&speed=20

Answer (score 4):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), <sup><s>53</s> \$\cdots\$ <s>43</s></sup> 42 bytes

```c
f(*l,n){*l^=l[1]^(l[1]=*l);n&&f(l+2,n-2);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nVLtToMwFP2/p2hIRgorUbqPRBH9YXyKfRhgZRJLR4BEdOHVxQstoyNLNDZpS3vOPffcWyIn4oE4NE2MbU6EdbL5zudrd7vD7erb3PKEacaYzygRDrW8uklEidIgEdhCpwmC0V6UrChf3fUW@ejkEkrmZEGWZFV7lwwqGbfEJTDHqJBokXyxY4ylpHWjjrY6E6TjdIRTaxC1O9VCispoomxomVmVsahk@949BW8L8L8iy2ss2tfY1aAn6ymSMMgSLVjxo7cgt2Fl0TvLJd/YVC90U909w1waBOnnuaHi4mOOcGsnEXtWQditpz4f@q70uYa@nG88NJt17P7hztY5SMledfjW02EkFArvM4YHQ8oMGBFdHj1HO7IcaDE2psV0D@Xh5Kkt8t4w4EH5Otlag2g9GQch5xEZlndpOoSUacD5McILW2hoytIo@8Qh4eQSiOFOjGUYyJyf7lr5WVAUwHH/VbWM7TbTRAwKRb6PQti9P7cn/LU902IjgN//UG06PSLOGcOhuqgndfMdxTw4FI3z8QM)

Inputs a pointer in an `int` array and the array's length (since pointers in C carry no length info).
Swaps every two elements in place.

Comment: this also modifies past the end of the array

Comment: @att I know, what's the problem?

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 35 bytes

```python
def f(m):*m[1:],_,m[::2]=*m,m[1::2]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/PyU1TSFNI1fTSis32tAqVideJzfaysoo1lYrVwckAmT@T7SNNtQx0jHWMdEx1TGLtS4oyswr0UjUtE4DETAeF1iZgQ4Q41LyHwA)

In-place. Essentially a golfed version of `m[1::2],m[::2]=m[::2],m[1::2]`

Comment: Is there something special about the 3.8 prerelease?

Comment: @ChrisBouchard it just happens to be the latest version available on tio. The walrss operator can be useful for glfing.

Comment: I guess TIO just hasn't updated their python in a while? 3.8 was fully released Oct 2019, 3.9 is the most recent full release, and 3.10 is the current pre-release.

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 29 bytes

```r
function(l)l[seq(!l)+2*1:0-1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfpmCj@z@tNC@5JDM/TyNHMye6OLVQQzFHU9tIy9DKQNcw9n@ahqGVmeZ/AA)

Comment: As input is guaranteed to be of length at least 2, you can omit the `!`.

Answer (score 4):

## [Desmos](https://desmos.com/calculator), <s>39</s> 38 bytes

```
l=[1...L.length]
f(L)=L[l-1+2mod(l,2)]
```

[Try It On Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/xmsjvpha3x)

[Try It On Desmos! - Prettified](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/qvcvjcjjpe)

Answer (score 4):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 26 bytes

```ruby
->l{r=-1;l.map{l[1^r+=1]}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6nushW19A6Ry83saA6J9owrkjb1jC2tvZ/gUJadLShjpGOsY6JjqmOWWzsfwA)

Answer (score 4):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 9 bytes

```
[:,_2|.\]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/o6104o1q9GJi/2tyKXClJmfkK6QpGCoYKRgrmCiYKpj9BwA)

Answer (score 4):

## T-SQL, 32 bytes

Input is a table variable

```sql
SELECT a FROM @ ORDER BY b+b%2*2
```

**[Try it online](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1511250/swap-every-two-elements-in-a-list)**

Answer (score 4):

## [4](https://github.com/urielieli/py-four), 22 bytes

```
3.72082072152152072094
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##M/n/31jP3MjAwsjA3MjQFISADANLk///DY2MTUzNAA)

Readable + explanation:

```
3. 720 820 721 521 520 720 9 4
^^------------------------------ mandatory prefix
   ^^^-------------------------- initial input in cell 20
       ^^^-----------------^---- loop while cell 20 is nonzero
           ^^^------------------ input to cell 21
               ^^^-------------- output cell 21
                   ^^^---------- output cell 20
                       ^^^------ input to cell 20
                           ^---- end loop
                             ^-- exit
```

Corresponding [Quartic](https://esolangs.org/wiki/User:Conor_O%27Brien/Compilers/Quartic) program:

```
decl a, b
input a
loop a
  input b
  print b
  print a
  input a
end
```

Answer (score 4):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), <strike>43</strike> 41 bytes

```
{for(;++n<NF;n++)$n+=$(n+1)-($(n+1)=$n)}1
```

*Thanks for Dominic van Essen for 2 less bytes!*

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v@/Oi2/SMNaWzvPxs/NOk9bW1MlT9tWRSNP21BTVwNC26rkadYa/v9vqGCkYKxgomCqYAYA)

```
{
for(;++n<NF;n++)        Starts a loop though the numbers.
                        n has to start as 1, because $0 is the whole line.
$n+=$(n+1)-($(n+1)=$n)  Swap the numbers two by two.
                        Readable: a += b - (b = a)
}
1                       Prints the line.
```

Comment: If you swap ```++n``` for ```n=1``` (same bytes), it'll also work for subsequent lines of input...  (currently the second 'try it online' line fails)

Comment: You are right!! Thanks for that.

Comment: ...or [41 bytes](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v@/Oi2/SMNaWzvPxs/NOk9bW1MlT9tWRSNP21BTVwNC26rkadYa/v9vqGCkYKxgomCqYAYA) if you don't care about subsequent lines (and I don't think you need to care about them here...)

Answer (score 4):

## [CLC-INTERCAL](https://esolangs.org/wiki/CLC-INTERCAL), <s>95</s> 67 bytes.

Why does CLC-INTERCAL 1.-94.-2 lack `!1~.1'`? I could have golfed off one byte.

```
DOCOMEFROM#9(1)DOWRITEIN.1+.2DDOCOMEFROM'.1~.1'~#1(9)DOREADOUT.2+.1
```

[Copy and paste to try it online!](http://golf.shinh.org/check.rb)

### Usage

- Each item of list must be in `ONE` to `SIX FIVE FIVE THREE FIVE` (inclusive); `ZERO` for end of list.

  - Given from STDIN, delimited with a LF.
- Outputs to STDOUT, as roman number.

### Try these inputs

```
ONE
TWO
ONE
TWO
ZERO
```

```
ONE
TWO
THREE
FOUR
FIVE
SIX
ZERO
```

Answer (score 4):

## [BQN](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/), <s>10</s> 9 bytes<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/mlochbaum/BQN/blob/master/commentary/sbcs.bqn)</sup>

-1 byte thanks to [Razetime](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80214/razetime)!

```
⥊·⌽˘∘‿2⊸⥊
```

[Run online!](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=RiDihpAg4qWKwrfijL3LmOKImOKAvzLiirjipYoKCkbCqCAoMOKAvzHigL8w4oC/MSnigL8oMSvihpU2KQ==)

`∘‿2⥊` Reshape the input into a matrix with 2 columns and and the necessary number of rows.
`⌽˘` Reverse horizontally (Swap the 2 columns).
`⥊` Flatten into a vector.

An alternative using the *Under* operator at 10 bytes:

```
⌽˘⌾(∘‿2⊸⥊)
```

[Try it online!](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=RiDihpAg4oy9y5jijL4o4oiY4oC/MuKKuOKliikKCkbCqCAoMOKAvzHigL8w4oC/MSnigL8oMSvihpU2KQ==)

Comment: useful userscript: https://github.com/razetime/userscripts/blob/main/bqncgcc.user.js

Comment: @Rezetime thanks and thanks! I already read that *Nothing* is supposed to be useful in trains, now I see why

Comment: TIL about using `∘` with Reshape, fascinating.

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jellylanguage), 4 bytes

```
s2UF
```

[Try It Online!](https://jht.hyper-neutrino.xyz/tio#WyIiLCJzMlVGIiwiIiwiIixbIjEsMiwzLDQsNSw2Il1d)

```
s2    Slices of length 2
  U   Reverse each
   F  Flatten
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) -p, 21 bytes

```perl
s/(\S+) (\S+)/$2 $1/g
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/79YXyMmWFtTAUzqqxgpqBjqp///b6hgpGCsYKJgqmDGZaBgqADE//ILSjLz84r/6xYAAA)

Comment: [Almost identical in sed](https://tio.run/##K05N0U3PK/3/v1hfIyZYW1MBTOrHGCnEGOqn//9vqGCkYKxgomCqYMZloGCoAMT/8gtKMvPziv/rugIA)

Comment: [Very similar in Retina](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P9fIyZYW1MBTHKpGCmoGP7/b6hgpGCsYKJgqmDGZaBgqADEAA "Retina 0.8.2 – Try It Online")

Comment: [Similar solution in Pip](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P8/Mag4PChBIyZYWzMhIcZIIcYw4f///4YKRgrGCiYKpgpmCoYGCiZGAA), though it's not the shortest Pip solution

Answer (score 3):

## [Add++](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/AddPlusPlus), 57 bytes

```
a:?
b:0
n:0
m:3
`b
Ea,Ib=n,,b:1,,x:i,+1,Ib=m,,b:0,,Oi,,Ox
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xJKSj4/z/Ryp4rycqAKw@Ic62MuRKSuFwTdTyTbPN0dJKsDHV0KqwydbQNQSK5IBEDHR3/TCCu@P//f7ShjpGOsY6JjqmOWSwA)

Input is the first argument.

Answer (score 3):

## [Raku](http://raku.org/), <s>19</s> 17 bytes

<s>*.flatmap:{$^b,$^a}</s>

```
*[^* »+»<1 -1>]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPtfKzpOS@HQbu1Du20MFXQN7WL/WysUJ1YqKKnEK9jaKVSnKajE1yoppOUXKQAVGCkYK5gomCqY2eko2BgoGCoAsd1/AA)

- `*[...]` is an anonymous function that slices into the list given as the sole argument using the bracketed expression, which is another anonymous function.
- `^* »+» <1 -1>` takes the numbers from 0 up to one less than the argument, and produces a new list by alternatively adding 1 and -1.  Those reordered indices are used to slice into the original input array.

Answer (score 3):

## APL+WIN, 17 bytes

Prompts for vector

```
,⌽((.5×⍴r),2)⍴r←⎕
```

[Try it online! Thanks to Dyalog Classic](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v@ob6qvz6O2CcZcQJanP5BlyPWooz3tv86jnr0aGnqmh6c/6t1SpKljpAmigfJAdf@BKrj@p3EZKhgpGCuYKJgqmHGlcRkoGCoAMRcXAA)

Answer (score 3):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform) with `Linq`, <s>32</s> 26 bytes

```cs
a=>a.Select((n,i)=>a[i^1])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY/NSsRAEITPyVM0wUMGZgPr3yUml0VFURBy8BAijGMTGpKZdXriIiHPHmcTD7Ieq7r5qkrzRluH88BkWqi@2WOfx39V9kTm88Ta2a5D7ckazu7RoCOdx7pTzPDibOtUD2PMXnnScDcYfUPG1418uDVDj069d3h0yhL4oPZczKooVVbhkZmmRpIIuqa3bSPmPI5@QV@WPuBZkUnZu1CmbkC5lkWIiqIlAMjsBw8FGDzA6oywlXAu4ULCpYQrCdcwBWS0C9Vth9mrI49hIaZnyVgt3OzRhoxEJnLliQk2Jfw/Lt3T9UVMiQjYKZ7mHw)

*-8 bytes thanks to m90's [witchcraft](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/59572249#59572249)*

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 73 bytes

```cs
a=>{for(int i=0,d=0;i<a.Length;i++){d=a[i];a[i]=a[++i];a[i]=d;}return a;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY@9asQwEIRr@ykGk8LGOnP5bXRyE0gRLhC4IoVxIWzFWbiTDknOEYye3VHspEozDLPLN7ud23TGqnl0pAccvpxXJ552R@kcXq0ZrDxhSp2Xnjo8jbrbkfZNyxat4S7y7MQsRT29G5vHFCS2rBdbTjtZ7ZUe/AensiymXsiGWv4j0ZXln@95sMqPVkPyMPM0@S37NNTjRZLOnbfxuKaFtIMr4jlJstSD9Hn0ENDqgjWZcM1ww3DLcMdwz/CAEJHJo9HOHFX1ZsmrPWmVX2XTYeFWzyZ2ZCxjK68I2NT4P1xezdeVImRFxIY0zN8)

Answer (score 3):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org), 18 bytes

```
for a b;<<<$b<<<$a
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724qjhjwYKlpSVpuhab0vKLFBIVkqxtbGxUkkBEIkQCKr822lDHSMdYx0THVMcsFioIAA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `sequences.merged`, <sup><s>34</s></sup> 29 bytes

```
[ 2 group unzip swap 2merge ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYw7DsIwEAX7nOKdIILwKaChQzQ0iApRGLNYFsFedm0hQDm7MSmmePOkuRmbopTjYbffruAkZvbBwahGq7iTBOqh9MwULGn7IHF0BQul9GbxIWHdNF9M0WGGORZYYqh7Us2foZzqM2aRw8cz9GUY3djBuVz8Bq3C9mSk/AA)

### Explanation

```
        ! { 1 2 3 4 5 6 }
2 group ! { { 1 2 } { 3 4 } { 5 6 } }
unzip   ! { 1 3 5 } { 2 4 6 }
swap    ! { 2 4 6 } { 1 3 5 }
2merge  ! { 2 1 4 3 6 5 }
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Rockstar](https://codewithrockstar.com/), 98 bytes

```
Listen to B
cut B with ","
I is 0
while I is less than B
shout B at I+1
shout B at I
Build I up up
```

[Try it online!](https://codewithrockstar.com/online)
(Must manually copy-paste code)

Takes input as comma-separated string of numbers eg:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6
```

Outputs as newline-separated string of numbers eg:

```
2
1
4
3
6
5
```

Rockstar has no modulo, and no bitwise operators, so porting the other solutions is out of the question.

#### Explanation

```
Listen to B             ; Read input to B
cut B with ","          ; Split B on ","
I is 0                  ; Set I to 0
while I is less than B  ; While I < B.length
                        ; (Rockstar Arrays automatically coerce to length when used as a scalar)
shout B at I+1          ; Print B[I+1] with trailing newline
shout B at I            ; Print B[I] with trailing newline
Build I up up           ; Increment I twice (each 'up' increments)
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 4 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
ò mé
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=8iBt6Q&input=WzEsMiwzLDQsNSw2XQo)

```
ò      - chunks of 2
  mé   - rotate each
```

Comment: This outputs a 2d list, you can use `c` instead of `m` to fix it

Comment: @noodle man Theoretically it does return a 2d list but in practice you need the Q flag to output it by implicit output, your suggestion to use c' method instead of m' is correct though

Comment: Yeah, I know, I was just in the mood for making pointless corrections :)

Answer (score 3):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 37 bytes

```
func[a][foreach[b c]a[print[c lf b]]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcG5DYAwEATAnCq2Bd6AMkhXG5izTyAhgyyo/5hpJcdWMqjOV4R/1ZhEv1tJdnCHKfFpZ31puBy7pHCwx4ARE2Ysih8)

### Alternative

Much longer but more fun approach using `parse`:

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 59 bytes

```
func[a][parse a[collect[any[b: skip keep skip keep(b/1)]]]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dcg7DkBAFEbh3ir@kkq8xTK0N7eYx51ECJNBYfVDp@FUJ18QG0exIE7cgOjO1ZBi8irsAkVmWxYxB6n1Ij1gnyePWcS/l@q8yPgp@rBpgQMVKFGhRoOWky9F9@foOd4)

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
2ôí˜
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f6PCWw2tPz/n/P9pQx0jHWMdEx1THLBYA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeV/o8NbDq89Pee/zv/oaEMdIx1jHRMdUx2zWJ1oAx1DHSCOjQUA).

**4 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage) alternatives:**

```
ιRø˜
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//3M6gwztOz/n/P9pQx0jHWMdEx1THLBYA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeX/czuDDu84Pee/zv/oaEMdIx1jHRMdUx2zWJ1oAx1DHSCOjQUA).

```
2ô€`
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f6PCWR01rEv7/jzbUMdIx1jHRMdUxiwUA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeV/o8NbHjWtSfiv8z862lDHSMdYx0THVMcsVifaQMdQB4hjYwE).

**Explanation:**

```python
2ô   # Split the (implicit) input-list into parts of size 2
     #  i.e. [1,2,3,4,5,6] → [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]
  í  # Reverse each pair
     #  → [[2,1],[4,3],[6,5]]
   ˜ # Flatten the list of pairs
     #  → [2,1,4,3,6,5]
     # (after which this list is output implicitly as result)

ι    # Uninterleave the (implicit) input-list, using 2 as implicit second argument
     #  i.e. [1,2,3,4,5,6] → [[1,3,5],[2,4,6]]
 R   # Reverse it
     #  → [[2,4,6],[1,3,5]]
  ø  # Zip/transpose, swapping rows/columns
     #  → [[2,1],[4,3],[6,5]]
   ˜ # Flatten the list of pairs
     #  → [2,1,4,3,6,5]
     # (after which this list is output implicitly as result)

2ô   # Split the (implicit) input-list into parts of size 2
     #  i.e. [1,2,3,4,5,6] → [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]
  €  # Map over each pair:
   ` #  Pop and push the pair to the stack
     # (€` is usually used to flatten a multi-level list one level down. One side-effect
     # is that the items are dumped in reversed order, which is what we want in this
     # case)
     #  → [2,1,4,3,6,5]
     # (after which this list is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 3):

## Pure [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 32 + 1 = 33 bytes

One additional byte for filename specification: `x`.

```bash
echo "$2
$1"
shift 2
(($#))&&. x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Dcm9DkAwGEbhvVfxpRohQqifMBA2o8ENIJVKBKFD7/7V5QzPWZdPwyzHSfEV5STSzjJl1UarG2SJi547eO7X0DTMYwu16duxZCLj7NPHbkiyIBBeGPp@QhZABokcBVKUqFwb1D8)

### Usage

- Input from program arguments.
- Outputs to stdout.

---

## Pure [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 34 + 1 = 35 bytes

One additional byte for filename specification: `x`.

```bash
read x
read y||>x
echo "$y
$x"
. x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvhfkpiZo6Cbp22soGJgV8GVWpGarJAElFAAsQvyi0oUAhxDPGz/F6UmpgDFwFRlTQ1IaXJGvoKSSiWXSoUSl55Cxf//hlxGXMZcJlymXAZcEDaYBgA)

### Usage

- Each item is given from STDIN.
- Outputs to STDOUT.
- Items are separated by a LF.

Answer (score 3):

## [Whitespace](https://web.archive.org/web/20150618184706/http://compsoc.dur.ac.uk/whitespace/tutorial.php), 65 bytes

```
[N
S S N
_Create_Label_LOOP][S S S N
_Push_0][S N
S _Duplicate_0][T   N
T   T   _Read_STDIN_as_integer][T   T   T   _Retrieve_input1][S N
S _Duplicate_input1][S N
S _Duplicate_input1][T  N
T   T   _Read_STDIN_as_integer][T   T   T   _Retrieve_input2][T N
S T _Print_input2_as_integer][S S S T   S T S N
_Push_10][S N
S _Duplicate_10][T  N
S S _Print_10_as_character][S N
T   _Swap_top_two][T    N
S T _Print_input1_as_integer][T N
S S _Print_10_as_character][N
S N
N
_Jump_to_Label_LOOP]
```

Letters `S` (space), `T` (tab), and `N` (new-line) added as highlighting only.
`[..._some_action]` added as explanation only.

Whitespace doesn't have lists, so I/O are newline delimited (strictly non-negative<sup>*†*</sup>) integers.

[**Try it online**](https://tio.run/##K8/ILEktLkhMTv3/n0tBAYiAmEuBk4sTBBTAQlAOJ5AFlOZU4IQqAakFi3KClXFx/f9vyGXEZcxlwmXKZQYA) (with raw spaces, tabs and new-lines only).

**Explanation in pseudo-code:**

```
LOOP:
  Integer a = STDIN as integer
  Integer b = STDIN as integer
  Print b as integer to STDOUT
  Print '\n' as character to STDOUT
  Print a as integer to STDOUT
  Print '\n' as character to STDOUT
  Go to next iteration of LOOP
```

This will stop with an error automatically when there are no more inputs.

<sup>*†*: For every second input it will use the input before it as heap-address (`[SNS_Duplicate_input1][SNS_Duplicate_input1][TNTT_Read_STDIN_as_integer]`), so the inputs should be strictly non-negative, since negative heap addresses aren't allowed in Whitespace.</sup>

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>49</s> 39 bytes

```python
lambda l:[l[c^1]for c in range(len(l))]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUSHHKjonOjnOMDYtv0ghWSEzT6EoMS89VSMnNU8jR1Mz9n9BUWZeiUaaRrShjpGOsY6JjqmOWaym5n8A)

-10 with thanks to @MannyQueen for an awesome tip.

Simply because no-one has submitted a Python 2 answer yet.

Answer (score 3):

## [Vim](https://www.vim.org), 11 bytes

```
qqddpj@qq@q
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v/v7AwJaUgy6Gw0KHw/39DLiMuYy4TLlMuMwA)

Explanation:

```
qq    @qq@q # Loop:
  dd        #  Delete the line
    p       #  Paste it below the next line
     j      #  Move down a line
```

Answer (score 3):

## APL, 15 bytes

```
{,⌽⍵⍴⍨(2÷⍨≢⍵)2}
```

The same idea as in the existing solution, but implemented as a separate function and two bytes less.

Answer (score 3):

## [Nibbles](http://golfscript.com/nibbles/index.html), <s>3.5</s> 3 bytes (6 nibbles)

```
\+\`/~
```

```
   `/      # chunks of input
     ~     # (using default size = 2),
  \        # reverse,
 +         # concatenate,
\          # and reverse again.
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

## [Desmos](https://desmos.com/calculator), <s>42</s> 38 bytes

-4 bytes thanks to @aiden's suggestion and wackscope variables

```
l=[1...L.length]
f(L)=L[l-1+2mod(l,2)]
```

[Try It On Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/kn8lqybapn)

Comment: Nice answer! Though when you use a list comprehension like that, it is golfier to just move `l` to its own line like `l=[1...L.length]`, and don't use a list comprehension entirely. See my [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/237085/swap-every-two-elements-in-a-list/237146#237146) to this question, for example.

Comment: Yeah we can move it to its own line but the question asked for a function and so when I have to move `l` to its own line I'll have to also account for l(L) which will consume more if not the same number of bytes

Comment: @AidenChow wackscope variables did the trick! thanks

Comment: @Steffan Ah right, I see that it worked for me because of some desmos extension I had and the space was to make sure it pasted 2*mod(l,2) instead of mod(2l,2). Anyways, how do I revert it back to the previous edit?
Edit: found it 

Answer (score 3):

## [sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/) `-n`, 10 bytes

```
2~2{G;p};h
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K05N0U3PK/3/36jOqNrduqDWOuP/f0MDAy5DA0MgNgJiYyA2AWLTf/kFJZn5ecX/dfMA)

- `2~2{G;p}` For even numbered lines, append hold space into pattern space and print
- `h` For all lines, replace hold space with pattern space.  This means that the hold space will always contain the previous, odd-numbered line when we are on an even-numbered line.

Comment: Can you get 10 bytes without `-n`?

Answer (score 3):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip) `-xp`, <s>5</s> <s>8</s> 7 bytes

```
R_MF<>a
```

[Try It Online!](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJwaXAiLCIiLCJSX01GPD5hIiwiIiwiIiwiWzE7MjszOzQ7NTs2XSAteHAiXQ==)

Comment: This solution works for strings, but since the challenge specifies lists, I'd say you need list I/O and a `FL` in front of the `R`.

Comment: @DLosc does the list need to be flattened? It doesn't seem to be specified in the question...

Comment: The question is a tad underspecified, but in such cases I'd err on the side of what the OP probably intended: list of integers in, modified list of integers out.

Comment: @DLosc Alright, love pip btw :)

Comment: Thanks! :D Actually, I just realized you can get it down to 7 bytes using map-flatten: `R_MF<>a`

Answer (score 3):

## [Rockstar](https://codewithrockstar.com/), 63 bytes

Takes input as a space separated string, outputs each element on its own line. 9 bytes could be saved if we were guaranteed every element of the array was a single digit by taking input with no delimiting spaces.

```
listen to S
cut S with " "
while S
roll S in N
say roll S
say N
```

[Try it](https://codewithrockstar.com/online) (Code will need to be pasted in)

```
listen to S        :Read the input string into variable S
cut S with " "     :Split S to an array on spaces
while S            :While S is not empty
roll S in N        :  Pop the first element from S into variable N
say roll S         :  Pop the first element from S and output it
say N              :  Output N
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 4 bytes

```
2ẇRf
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=2%E1%BA%87Rf&inputs=%5B1%2C2%2C3%2C4%2C5%2C6%5D&header=&footer=)

Explanation:

```
2ẇ   # Split list into groups of two
  R  # Reverse each group
   f # Flatten
```

Comment: In 2.6pre1 this is 3 bytes - `ǒ` splits into chunks of 2

Comment: @emanresuA Oh, nice! I still have yet to check out the prerelease, I'll have to do that. You can also get three bytes in this version by using `y$Y`, which is just the flagless version of my flaggy answer.

Answer (score 2):

## [Grok](https://github.com/AMiller42/Grok-Language), 11 bytes

```
:Y}:zpz
  q
```

[Try it Online!](http://grok.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%3AY%7D%3Azpz%0A%20%20q&inputs=1%0A2%0A3%0A4%0A5%0A6)

Explanation:

```
:Y      # Get input and copy it to the register
  }     # Quit if no more input
  q
   :z   # Print next input
     pz # Print value in the register
```

Answer (score 2):

## [ayr](https://github.com/ZippyMagician/ayr), 6 bytes

```
,_2,`/
```

## Explained

```
 _2 … /    pairwise reduce
    ,`     By reverse concatenation
,         Ravel
```

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), 31 bytes

```
%{If(++$i%2){$j=$_}Else{$_,$j}}
```

Input comes from the pipeline.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfmvklhUlFipYKtgqGOkY6xjomOqY8alUpRaXJpTAhSFStf8V632TNPQ1lbJVDXSrFbJslWJr3XNKU6tVonXUcmqrf2vpKIBVaublZ@Zp6Cuo66poKtrpwAUh5qGkFD6DwA)

Try it in a PS console:

```
$array = 1,2,3,4,5,6
$result = $array |
%{If(++$i%2){$j=$_}Else{$_,$j}}
"$($array -join ',') --> $($result -join ',')"
```

### Explanation

**%** is an Alias for the Cmdlet "ForEach-Object", which accepts input from the pipeline and processes each incoming object inside the ScriptBlock {...}
**If(++$i%2)** first increments $i (which starts at 0) in each loop and takes it modulo 2
If the result is 1:
**{$j=$_}** the current element will be saved in in $j
Otherwise (0):
**{$_,$j}** first puts the current element, then the element from the last loop iteration into the pipeline/stdout.

Answer (score 2):

## [Add++](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/AddPlusPlus), 10 bytes

```
L,2$T€bRbF
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xJKSj4/99Hx0gl5FHTmqSgJLf/KjmJuUkpiQqGdvZc/v//RxvqGOkY65jomOqYxQIA)

Uses Add++'s much more powerful functional mode, rather than it's [vanilla mode](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/237094/66833). However, definitely check out the other Add++ answer, as it doesn't use any form of indexing, just looping!

### How it works

```
L,2$T€bRbF - Unnamed lambda function. Takes 1 argument, L
L,         - Define the lambda:
  2$T      - Split into runs of length 2
     €     - Over each:
      bR   -   Reverse it
        bF - Flatten and return
```

Answer (score 2):

## TI-Basic, <s>19</s> 17 bytes

```
seq(Ans(I-i²^I),I,1,dim(Ans
```

<sup>`i` represents the imaginary number.</sup>

Takes input in `Ans`. Output is stored in `Ans` and is displayed.

-2 bytes thanks to [MarcMush](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/98541/marcmush).

Comment: -2 bytes: `(⁻1)` => `²`

Answer (score 2):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 10 bytes

```
N{riripp}h
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/36@6KLMos6CgNuP/f0MuIy5jLhMuUy4zAA)

#### Explanation

```
N           e# Push newline (this is truthy)
 {      }h  e# Do while without popping the condition: infinite loop
  r         e# Read line and push string to the stack
   i        e# Interpret as integer
    r       e# Read line and push string to the stack
     i      e# Interpret as integer
      p     e# Pop and print with a newline
       p    e# Pop and print with a newline
            e# Implicitly print stack: newline
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 27 bytes

```
l->[l[i-(-1)^i]|i<-[1..#l]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Fcc9CoAwDEDhqwRdWkjE@jepFwkRXJRAkSAOCt691uHB@2w9lXZLG0wp0syRlRwFv6i8OhKHqiqjSFrN4uNuoBns1OPKW/woYHO39wjMARtsscMeB8muMWBOxKcP)

Answer (score 2):

## x86-16 machine code, <del>8</del> 7 bytes

```
00000000: aca4 aa49 e2fa c3                        ...I...
```

Listing:

```
    TWO_LOOP: 
AC      LODSB               ; load first byte (into AL) 
A4      MOVSB               ; move second byte into first byte 
AA      STOSB               ; store first byte (from AL) into second byte 
49      DEC  CX             ; only loop half as many times as length 
E2 F9   LOOP TWO_LOOP 
C3      RET
```

Callable function: input list at `[SI]`, output to `[DI]` length in `CX`.

-1 bytes thx to @m90!

Comment: Improvement: `lodsb; movsb; stosb`

Comment: @m90 ooh that's nice! Thx!

Answer (score 2):

## [Pxem](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Pxem), 18 + 0 = 18 bytes.

The configure is:

- No breaking loop when insufficient items.
- Abort to illegal integer input.

Filename:

```
.w._._.n .o.n .o.a
```

Content is empty.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pTp7X@LIsv/nU7QRhQghgI46YpxFBx3OKHgU78wecfKL0EgUEjYdFB/cr763qrvzxJnds1dHhnQ9urpeXdWdZ5uN/lxdMW4d12AjRVkl0zmdlCcPAZ1My3RyW556zJk7bFImjqv3vQEl54ABDwH1pz6Fz7KyCnTH1A5mPmXwRHRy5E2mduDcjil5coIRcR/KecaJ3AEdEDalQ2fo9AHFcznB4XNA9ZnrBKQ/sn27D3z5eNsjbAxCEtfziTsbj8kQvgydMXXtCeUol4FP7Ynu@Q4F/gPSMjpcom@@E8B85Pa5TLpTmx7bTy/URfmOHdcek9l0YAe0TGqVWrVc2SlvVslV96j4ETFOnT51GQCPgHfgPFJc0cRzGfkP9T3yCARl1NYdDch557L1ffxM2AwU4jA6powR6j46vudOQCSFAZJOZ8psYrMHUqns7JBVWE8AX2u1OrEZX5PQuULnU88PyOmR1Tg9NY@U4HlKcZq@5w7JgTGgjwZXQ@1gvUrW1wW8D8LZ7uA9uOR33uh@MdVcIcTUpxFTBAF6RKrlXnGouLcQX/SFGnK5are@W5fdz2atUtmERaDcX871q@/RNKiL09@to87FRfOoa1Yl0kn76s9Vcn7VJb93ri7I@ffmGbmEb0dN8qV50VSOW6fNduOsaebLT2ULfl1S9sSHnVeOOu1us901Ffx23Dox88ph86TVflUIIVeXTevwyKzW8eHwotn4ap12OufWty/NttVqX14dH7eOWkhe4SiNw85F1zq86HwFOGJKUjHeOj1tnjROgbDbPGleIGyRB9H7I9p/cNy72PWcIVKBxd1gSNZYr@cSNReuQyVvCL3z6ZTofxC9SXr4DD/5wo@36x@93o3W6xUqbxX8x/8qWuH6R0XfvXnLaXmiBCPqIgntjzzSRotGgQFxFIlBqgfrNY43h9ipKkNH@eeSGW9J4T7svFXwDz4Somn5tGiXPDr/QiLQnzdzA5DJu/PtiYIuMUeipFxqTtpZTQxHY3Uy8JLLugWkOSyGPPWJ3heTDjyXKiIiRDQtBcTbG@FOI8AFrSDXzkP0SD4MHD@YTCFaXrtn559bF3sYAQLUtxmFiQWGiiso5POaBMakBnzIwXq9YLyDUI7BG8tgmFp8WzOiqet1yuy@fOBJkGsbRMiFqyjEjJwhuSa6T/j6Zz6EvDchN5AQcLifGa6T0KTRjwcpokFcogdksEX0NoGPxxRZjE7HjKaIC1OG1LpHps6gRANnQkvT/nRWemQvYEfIuprwwvemm/GZ0uDAB@swUqnWNrc@bO/sfiT56567cZPP4HGvLmeJbWdMdJds1TIABptFnhk/yhu9Qrn3uttb9LSc0asaWbb20wPKZJt6rbq1s7W7ub21S/IplFe7aOYq9UWz/fmVuyixFwkMCALxJV44Ms2/xigM1VrIVbR6ggxNDL5pqvZtf0CHdyPn/mE8cb3pHz4LZo9P8@eXxuHR5@bxyZfWv76enrU75/@@uOxe/c@377//J1aXpSaYnpoQqHfBqBByT83o@QUHsp6zb1YrdadY1F5T60T4PcDvAb5Vvwd4ChwHKJvdssCP5ijBYIGvUNs41UrV5JwhEVGTYi7k10iNWpgCxM8eOYgi0cjxeVTc8LKChAnwF5hQxsx8l1TC@Mc0Il0bU5wqssUeGYIngc8EHuydLvXBj4lNEOT5tv/MM6Aapb@YbxUfNWWhKP0xtV0LxOBCFIRuee7RSe61ComG5D4p3OHtKcnnSfN7q0u@XJ0T2I/Iv6/g4bx13iSN04sz0m1enCGuPyH6EBYYslUjBvrfoud5OlcF@UIOWCiINWuq3MDRW1nfd6aBwlmnV/LX8yiRNUSeh11cPThICq1AaTIFDUqtJPN8VW5aySxRjbLEUnJAe6fyQzItrBLPv7Nd54WSsQObKRSC4KewswugT/veHYc@2mMHbf0AhaASJ4HPna65tS2iPy5C4GfMgErWGLhTTAbX1WrtxsQvu5UbU52qaVhVwHY@AszLwCoStgswNw2rfJCwTYA5KdhHAKlWeuijwN7eAVA/M4vktIucWAa2K2HbAHvMSCBXtYOrGmZgclXbuCqa4bkleQK96mdgUs5dlPMpDatJbeyiNuYZmJxvF@d7zsCknB9Rzpe0WnakmKgxOyPKtmQJ4qpBZnlSzB0Uc5KBSTG3UcxBCraFGi6mh3BmPTW0iVgr6SFUfy49hFOvRUPCH/kTz5ihO0Jv9uh4M2ZKL7/m/nkTkoWjxaIYx81LCUuHQkRsAvv19VwFywyYPLkZ4E7AaXWzVudfxKeua8upfaiGwbY26Llq6X2hoo0A15mrROOLaHW4vcYlUOGn8/7dSRf5MCs8jZz@iHhDgnsqbAGUQW6f2AEMYgf7SWDR8l2ZPJH5fI6Z3wu/PgkoFF22IMXujhOXeGlFmGEbDYNg5@XcQStLyXDmA8QXhMwjDVDxADtioL71MesQO5F2XMqC8aNZEYnH@HGNYt7kjFAbfDIUFCwqcJMm5eqou3QexI5i/LBjcrC5nMGsJI3MCdWGWuebRCVlkCTZwTLVULXX@qj2WDSBq@tJg0dCpexcrUeGsQcDMrZvocjkz2KwddbqNrqt9gk56XQ75BIemmfQJlySby3oZo87p6edbwhufPtKLtut8/Nmd0@Qcr@pC3FXxRo4exNyy3yuaq/wuQiBWNr@GqNcLieROQyeur4jKwUPP10oKeYOC7CD5LwEzSKxJMd1Ascej5@hDBIj4B5QYMDfyHsCPoGnA7lcBfdSdCfo4jlXCFDwJzL2PChUmJEzSkYGkzseosZ4hGP@JjHtJ3v@9GwL7L7nAt9ZGp8Zpd82YtZIYIcEtz61H5bZc4JwhsYeKgM3@jENKCx14AyHsEoIeVlzrZLOYfdbGAGCDS4dNPiE@ghDIrH/Ctuo6oKfqgj1gltRPGgSh0VQK5Op7QfCs94PIOGbxWLoi1C/FiDzlvCXs9RSwURUMY8q5kuF1fusdT3FGvUCvH/7@9yjiABVYH3nsjFWoPJEh6Fm7Sl02MABx0GhTAm7HCGZYBrJxQxjkXVwI4LlDPD08PE2sb4wqSb5TGdsVEjSasuU0GlNcwbkWajxVqC2DJ4LmjadBXiuUZh60I0LIsDzcgbI9BdI7hISni/e0SyekxPi4XkXcokhVgwJSWNgP8seEIMUY5bBQGAIe8wZsIdSn9F4bJgzEu0VBhg4vsV3MGy0@Axy9Nq5ichozgCP8T1cX4Kb/458iSZL6CDCDn0STQ1BZcE8g4K6rmraO47OnSIaj1w05GX3CoIdtstphr1qyFH693tMs64f8m3kDBnLn9S6zD80BAbp5QbeiNrTjKUnHIcDpEKGvjeRzyHSIGfwVBVppriSW9OFatAWBe3ArGm2DxvWBPyiz7XEkaMABI4DMC1Pe0PPg3DgkVaIDsXyvDiSeQk3m0SEQVTxcIStPsbnEkXBuHREqdm3nh9YqGjBRxNdMW8qXxPTztw@HqlDOeC4EvOVBXb/4doZmFCfVsTUotNKnr7FPBYRk4TXcVYlFm3yzBSqqgvmxaIzAOZK8gyhAk7OuGMnCgO0SSiPXi2Bl2cECo/7YnmiqQYUNw1ioT2RXL/57@Yr8vlAcQuS6TxX0RjJDrrOm2JFge0Kcrc4NYzOLKEtz4@c8nRO86RRhl/ikfLTyz3zyvflefml/FS2SXlOys/EfqBeeQADgzIt2@H5hThUyM3V9NLn0aLFQSaeF4BYKVnJ/n7@@Kp91G112pd5JTIV94/ChN0lmmcCj28qssAjCdEwiDPZOvKGqlMq5oY4jKCSE2OgKjKyGYFcP2ElUoHSY0DndBCigIe5znQ2Fjc4kRwyPF/lyUc0A5SVixhLGHQJKYHBDWc5sfOWIqxi8ca0nCQu5oAss5KuRxRJxsG7yBGqXk0ihxncckrWvdAs@pqFzmaBt4VURg0eE0dl1r0ZsbacqNpNjpnvza2/h5yBm9a9LDa4DTEY4L/JDNxUBsgTNhxihfzCAlJgIpTj1Ym8GOrCGaBv8@BKaCDOnyFeGH5ppXIctFcE5jYCyRwPPu5RPMbv6Xityss5GLfH0Plw4O0zSM7oHzPq9qmE3s6wiXq@peK20e7zizggxtuGGd42Jh1GbO4oQ@L4SO3Bz5qHbYjlKCkHi7Z8tG5fUEHuBbvGvUzIdeuDVsc2DUro0MTOhqlX47KP@0Ufdnarvx@er4Is8Jjwi5CdPBvlE5eqWnFrl7O3GZtx/TQuj1qt0MiRyGH9YvmRsLwvt2YugG5nw9j/fDMavI7b6DCBvgMKjevHKwL2WBiNwWdgXNuHxjCNLJefIE0Iy@eILJKcMh28DmNTu085luRU@LgPOOvrFp5Bb2lvbxBv5mZtwf3lzuMbM2F46gj5Sdi5oK4N1NI66BuQUhqLjIy2K6HG/TiQ6xjKcVm4AhZdX09IVA9XzBfKWZjyjJp7imlubQrxwEESrbQcCSniU57kdClNw1q3dt/ePuzshw4sxt@9lExscCLvq2Vrjx852C6RC4b/wdvUqK3gvWlMt0oGMxeaJWcI9ruDNO5j@xAbTeO@zgucYAQuyQhev3tBkkPna@N3Ah7F0oCU5evLh@zLzf4qwRsi3qsNnDsn4MUU@jDKUI@MtbUb@8WHnXrKdEnP96GBJjC5jmEVTbIsVspx@RWlO3DQb@xxZmNNFl5h6IXl3Cc1NEdoC3uPTMCJMJDLTyWoBODvuYQKLL9IgyRuzEIqlVhjmwW8jiZqgoWNNImIiatt/lmyeH9bshjFRyFfzMrkn5HL8iE8YE06WVhTL9lq5VfX6ZnUwXfhFXn@vVAyLhfV1vu1fziNWKbJp4nGxJrTg4llzlUtsjIn35cU7@A@Z3EPfo77ksVdMZPIcmt@Gj0Th9gT2MPkuYiDZ4qhIff42dQIQmxMGRk7EwdfXoHu7Y7iMaSMY1YCTpRNaV@cDUG@P/YpPbz8XCeV@c6x@MECDo9dJvac8AYbYLsV8YMw2FUUebKCkzr8sEBMTaA@HFNwF3LaaZ/wsKeDeHZ5LgoUBybZrJFbCE98Qeas8fthEzaqr/j@xcUl6XbI5@ZR63OTgAW7X5oXOAIgcniUCKa4qbK8Kc/G9yXrIYop8SpHHMyOtCzUU0smdvbDkkwiP0BywKQA9RHgWw/Zs0oAsXC34BX4Guupa334Y@QNL5F6vZVeLwf/bRgwcNtXuYAo533scfcmTA3gaGd8SEl1/05uhsj2phjS8fLlTWKcnkW9@6D9NHqAhYlXCBqJGn2ukqLs8@tZ1JUl1I2foepq6vA2RaRniAQdr6L3K5mD/vRsejWmWqSm/F/1Ord2k5r0p6YOrb0BADMz4ZKCX6jv6QPn0WHgbeoSj4zH/MppEjInVyb0lVM/WY5h3e9Zzhqw1DI72kKJOrSfdHCtdqubV9oXpll9ja/9LSiPB5Y8AIJKEk/GF4B1YNZg00sCw3gxqDvoG1p8BwBNv5Y8ql@IDlMcKRWLySMnfj0gDt8XCgqE3W7euw2ACWHezO9De8sb38IeNpCbWvIdMXl9nmmbOR4QvfP60WtldXXDWJDNAzxywPQjpwpv0gfyelleoPMMOsT39MbPSkHekoijLWgToA/9f73jknm75VG84JJ9uyWxS/83b7T89F2Wv76oXn6F5Z2XV957bSX91sov31cRb6osv6giXlERt/3lYfYKPno16x9exEfnHuiyciJh3fClMFGx/kPuGqZkqTneSUVMJs7dCNpLege@xl9F5dW9wlWUemuCE4JD8/gB54N2GeRBdUzsAN@6Q8WIHhabWqnjM3xXInyTsnFxYp01vqcCBUKIr3ur8nFbU0n45uKZYdbqZ7q5i7cWol/EXV@VOoeGVZFdJCOQHA7OpLFYneFVh/LKTAQslNiOjN8QzG0fqnW9RV5C@738WSU1sgkO/oFs/x8)

### Usage

- With STDIN and STDOUT.
- Each integer shall be given, separated by one or more space characters.
- Outputted separated with a space.

Answer (score 2):

## [Coconut](http://coconut-lang.org/), 48 bytes

```
l->(l[1::2],l[:-1:2])|*>zip|>reduce$(+)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85Pzs8rLfmfZhvzP0fXTiMn2tDKyihWJyfaStcQyNCs0bKryiyosStKTSlNTlXR0Nb8X1CUmVeikaYRbaijYKSjYKyjYKKjYKqjYBarqfkfAA)

Python equivalent:

```python
from functools import reduce
from operator import add
f = lambda l: reduce(add, zip(l[1::2], l[:-1:2]))
```

Answer (score 2):

## [C++ (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 50 bytes

```cpp
[](auto&v){for(int&i:v)swap(i,(&i)[int(&i)%8<1]);}
```

-5 bytes thanks to ceilingcat!

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY/BbsIwEETv/ooRVaO4OAcoBUoCP5LmYBkntUScyHbMIcqv17WhUvewO/u0mtGKcSw6IcKL0uI2XSUqNVhnJO8v5J95KdxgLoRMVukOmvfSjlxIWHctCVHaoedK50lw0wkG8c3NW9K@biiZCWI9XeBnbBi2DO8MO4YPhj3DgeHI8Ikl2qVbPrkBLc4IdZOnJfN0bgeTIjJ18tTe@ZgrlmeK1pGl@XqsNg0tl/Dn0eaelk8VYx8uUDjB0wdMJYbJoaoijm31pVclWcKPaG@8s6G4hyI@eBbr9ZaHoh2l6ZW1ystf)

Answer (score 2):

## [Burlesque](https://github.com/FMNSSun/Burlesque), 6 bytes

```
2co)^p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyotykktLixN/V@U@N8oOV8zruB/ccb/aEMdBSMdBWMdBRMdBVMdBbNYAA)

Improved: Remembered map shorthand

```
2co   # Chunks of 2
)^p   # Push in reverse for each block
```

## [Burlesque](https://github.com/FMNSSun/Burlesque), 7 bytes

```
2co{}^m
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyotykktLixN/V@U@N8oOb@6Ni73f3HG/2hDHQUjHQVjHQUTHQVTHQWzWAA)

```
2co   # Chunks of 2
{}^m  # Push in reverse for each block (strictly push-map with a nop)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 4 bytes

```
ṁ↔C2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//@HOxkdtU5yN/v//H22gY6hjpGOsY6JjqmOmY65joWMZCwA)

#### Explanation

```
ṁ↔C2
  C2  slices of length 2
ṁ↔    flatmap reverse
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 5 bytes

```
ġ₂↔ᵐc
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r//8jCR01Nj9qmPNw6Ifn//2hDHSMdYx0THVMds9j/UQA)

#### Explanation

```
ġ₂         Split the list in groups of 2 consecutive elements
  ↔ᵐ       Map reverse
    c      Concatenate
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Knight](https://github.com/knight-lang/knight-lang), 35 bytes

```
;=aP;=bP WaIb;Ob;Oa;=bN=aP Ia=bP=aP
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVhrc9NGFP2eX6GoNNZaiuJQSgcrSgbS0Mm0OClJy7S2wavV2hbIktEjCbXVv07vXb1WfoXOMIy1e/a@9tzH5iO9ozGLvHlyGIQu/8p8GsfKr4E3mSYXURRGCn9IeODGivhaZDngmkYxb@5LZ0rU2zRIvNnjuJsk4nS2YGEQJ1HKkjDSKFkkUy824zCNGLdpBjve/N3US3g8p4xrxf6MJmyqHb3X@oPhoD@IYT3rDvXld/33g2DY1gbB8gkh7SOSzTn/BLsRT9IoUCTh/c5wuQxS389yYY7B7A5Z@DxRqO2Y/IEzTYITqxCBR2zbpmf4oytDbOm3GacO2K5RUGP6PJgkU2LQPhuSLAnBcS@YbLQqy0Q4lNu/ri9u7P7QykP1J/VTvogTmnhMmeMtaA5ZOOZaeKwxRPGORuBDx6InQkyh36K6nvvHbLHep0OzlGV5Y42Rwh6WSb5mURqIsEfhvRLw@5wRmcuddLJhfYt3QohZbwKul84cHm3BlZuAexWGPqfBFmC1mxWs@g2CEVG/Il4euhWSxekcpRtC1AeXJhS4ljsqKdngTPFdn9vkSfHdBK25US7IMP7ZR/MKBFU8sJoGjIfj3GvJjYMDyXjgY/6rjAIKr0JQhGSNPyXX62y6fT0k/ZeHfw/bR8ZxRXl6cIAXjDI19VZFbSRz09m8cmZUOvNE5GdGRpmfTGtX9mtbDw5o49omMk6RcftNYJaTeZ7GUw1XiZWnykXvz8u3V703F71be5EVCXPp8iBZ4cBj7vfp4T8fhvh/5/DFBwjBagCEUDA228UmD0HApmZ8xFFv7AEuD1GOw0CBud4kQDmSJ/0aM6yomRu8BYUZfBd6rtLZx/spLbfqBJXrsjb6I/gUhPeB4lWWKa2Gaa1RM@bCBVLGV4rut9Jr4OrrIYWAFulCySqpio2aU9R1Ja6U52vO6FQqHSSDGrwTftiEz1J/J7zdhLvenexlvYU30biEUtQbmkxN4E3AJKlH4Pe2S1LPaRCEiQKq4E4U54vyD49CFUwN3f@pu1b4PX1UH4hP/VDSNw/vd@urxS@X@xo96ZBvcr7d/gbv@cM8DJCkNOHCICUJoTYGfAJ8u@MKGMcjMNLfUklO5HvbWm9OG6gG8Wva96Ah7ua9VL0r4veKkkpyzqOQRgkpKwi225UcUBGsEXVXZxDyCucfCSULZ2AmF0dMtQrG/zwlBwfXyuhAc3w0OEghx6ZSz1FbQwJzXDy4GbbPyOD4yHgqaIXRAGY5MpFAAw4r@RBDzXy4Q7DawrbElsuW2sIfpHapHlqx6IFVMy8AJrnK5zQEQvGAhSkuc7erPFnQbLSppQv7m3lkHHfIctlZqVnFgLCrZqETowJQKFwvPQiqdZkRn3MKvUeuQI8wvhq1djK@QsmXCotFd4VT1L35ErAuzeyIf069iGvqOFaJscARWWw50haber77YR6FjMeIev1H7/z28qp3U/fm11ADdrVmiSX5BcNkXonpO1KnEzctzaqWxKuzrsg6fWmSo5wxHOdpnI/xw4X52D1h5WzslrPx2BYWmaUpqGx/vIVObzzo3cFEodEkneHA8WTh6seZAkqUMXoJHdXBRmrxPLBjkkl3jIHQmOEYfGWkgCW2MlagOJvmvwM647aT/wbVsc3WZ1dxQDNNs0JVlSWv4ipqT7ww0FS9klqFx1HKkVMcpbqtGoqqO2Yuo@riurpWm66cj5wlphcL/howLmXjQpUS8YkXJ1y4SBYQ2mPsVeUDaeUtoak9MEmZpTDkOZCoD5Ql/hcFeoHCpjSCL5hZ/DCYQE2yaoLQoe1IGiEwVeeSr7ZIMniBao6UB0SuPfUYlb83rI00UHuhcoeSoVCmvou2ChXuPtRKKasw4MSoQqBeq4ZG7NPiSaaqhmO/SsdjHpnU90OmwQDuhhgkqnWAER2YyA2gvANPSuKA4Z8spoOr95BxXDuGLix2xEvOxNx650Hiq4NAJYTZzIx9D16IHUM5rCf7stIwksmWvc0ta7TusR@Cr8@evnj24vlPT188b4vViAZuOMOwyecvVIPapxgy2ghtDWm9bCGkSvQ8vIVVjtzdwICz0sxckjmOwtk5MOA8dGHQLN5OpFuaK1@nyQrcywRnNtnIV8JIKi@d50vF41L8L2@PxHbVh5rObXFU/V0cKgqiyR@81SouYfcrBeKt1XwANZC/VUj0WDakTCYZ/TNy67Qa3xrBLi2LEzdME/M@gsYNAvM8JwZtxOyqKajWWkhTBwPxPCz//AFUO9uioEB0jDL9AUu6G8Ej7JJ7I2JU05Nskw5kxXJSXxy23MLLRhgO15D4QtiEbK8hsUNvQh6tIcW7YAPy@3WZ4WY7368hxfy9AXlSISvSlEdwNqiOyGdOt5@ZbDtztv0MFv@NZw6qMxotM7zxF5uz4li3kYPLR4/RrrOem5Z0LN81NgXMlmCNKoOP2@USVEoP/WZKU7N4qTt2pd9pCH9XCV9gH7Ua6WuRlcTbSObLXAS0f/uUbgwWW/f9F@mQCFptt@E0nmsGNgLps6xlVTqikOVSVZtRuykUuEJFeegRVa7trmuuwGXW44B/RnWYL@uK4BCd6bVJuotduW4d/7bk2td8xAMOojP6atn02rKda@UdvXSsK/hH4bMHq8olVK5r@PF1BM9RD3uX9fV47@neD3vP9n7ce773Hw)

Answer (score 2):

## [rSNBATWPL](https://github.com/Radvylf/rSNBATWPL), 37 bytes

```
a~(a cond (a{1},0 a)+{a sfro 2}){+for
```

This is very golfed. It is "bad rSNBATWPL" in that it abuses the syntax very heavily. The ungolfed version of this is:

```
f = a ~ cond{a} {
    (a{1}, a{0}) conc f{a sfro 2}
} { cast.array{""} }
```

This is a simple recursive lambda function, which iterates pair-by-pair. Some golfs I made to this were:

- Removing whitespace and the unnecessary trailing `}`, of course
- Substituting `cast.array{""}` for `+for`, a very strange way of generating an empty array (works by iterating with a function, `+` in this case, over an empty array generated when `for` casts its right input, which is `Null`, to an array)
- Replacing `conc`, the concat function, with `+`
- Replacing `a{0}` with `0 a`, which calls `a` as a curried binary function. Its second argument is `Null`, and since calling any primitive value as a function with `Null` as its input returns it unchanged, this saves a byte for little cost
- Running `cond` as a binary function. Since rSNBATWPL functions/built-ins are curried, this saves a byte over applying the function three times (which is the traditional way of providing three arguments)
- Replacing `f=` and `f{...}` with an implicit recursive call. `.` is a variable which always refers to the current function, so `f{...}` can be replaced with `.{...}` to remove the `f=`, and any time there's a `{...}` without a function name, an implicit `.` is added, allowing me to save another byte by putting it after the `+`

Answer (score 2):

## [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno), \$ 6 \log_{256}(96) \approx \$ 4.94 bytes

```
ZlrzZS
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_wYKlpSVpuhbLonKKqqKCIRyo2IJN0YY6CkY6CsY6CiY6CqY6CmaxEBkA)

##### Explanation

```python
ZlrzZS  # Implicit input     [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
Zl      # Uninterleave       [[1, 3, 5], [2, 4, 6]]
  r     # Reverse            [[2, 4, 6], [1, 3, 5]]
   zZ   # Zip                [[2, 1], [4, 3], [6, 5]]
     S  # Sum (Flatten)      [2, 1, 4, 3, 6, 5]
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org) <sup>[SBCS](http://tinyurl.com/Uiua-SBCS-Feb-17)</sup>, 7 bytes

```
♭≡⇌↯∞_2
```

[Try it!](https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_9_0__ZiDihpAg4pmt4omh4oeM4oav4oieXzIKCmYgWzEgMiAzIDQgNSA2XQpmIFswIDEgMCAxXQo=)

-1 thanks to Bubbler

```
♭≡⇌↯∞_2
   ↯∞_2  # reshape into matrix with two columns
 ≡⇌      # reverse columns
♭        # deshape
```

Comment: Replace `≑~` with `≡` to save 1.

Comment: @Bubbler Of course, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

## [Labyrinth](https://github.com/m-ender/labyrinth), 13 bytes

```
??!
; \
,\!
@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0lMqizKzCvJ@P/f3l6Ry1ohhksnRpHL4f9/AwVDAwUTBV0jBQsFY@N/@QUlmfl5xf91UwA)

Takes a list of integers separated by any non-numeric non-null single byte, and prints newline-separated integers. It is important that the input does NOT have a trailing separator, since it is used to detect the end of input.

```
Loop: ??!\!\,;
??    Take two integers A and B [A B]
!\!\  Print B, newline, A, newline
,     Take the next separator, -1 on EOF
;     Continue loop if not EOF; discard the separator

End: @ (Halt)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 7 bytes

```
.n_McQ2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/Xy8v3jc50Oj//2hDHSMdYx0THVMds1gA)

- `cQ2` chunks of evaluated input in length of 2
- `_M` maps over reversal in the chunk matrix
- `.n` flattens it

Comment: [Natte](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/108444/natte)'s suggested a golf, -1 by replacing the `.n` with `s`

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 5 bytes

```
ＷＳ⟦Ｓι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/788IzMnVUHDM6@gtCS4pCgzL11DU1MhAMgo0YhGEdVRyIzVtP7/35DLiMuYy4TLlMuM679uWQ4A) Link is to verbose version of code. Takes newline-terminated input. Explanation:

```
ＷＳ
```

Repeat while there is still input...

```
⟦Ｓι
```

... output the subsequent input before it.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip) `-rp`, 7 bytes

```
WVRVUWg
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P8/PCwoLDQ8/f9/Qy4jLmMuEy5TLjMuQwMuE6P/ukUFAA)

#### Explanation

The flags are for input & output formatting: `-r` reads the program arguments from lines of stdin; `-p` formats the output as a list rather than concatenating it.

```
      g  List of arguments
    UW   Unweave into a pair of lists, each consisting of every other element
  RV     Reverse the order of those two lists
WV       Weave them back together
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Core Maude](http://maude.cs.illinois.edu/w/index.php/The_Maude_System), 115 bytes

```
mod S is pr LIST{Nat}. op f : Nat ~> Nat . var A B : Nat . eq f(A B X:[Nat])=
B A f(X:[Nat]). eq f(nil)= nil . endm
```

The result is obtained by reducing the `f` function with the input list.

#### Example Session

```
Maude> red f(1 2 3 4 5 6) .  --- Expected: 2 1 4 3 6 5
result NeList{Nat}: 2 1 4 3 6 5
Maude> red f(0 1 0 1) .  --- Expected: 1 0 1 0
result NeList{Nat}: 1 0 1 0
```

#### Ungolfed

```
mod S is
    pr LIST{Nat} .

    op f : Nat ~> Nat .

    var A B : Nat .

    eq f(A B X:[Nat]) = B A f(X:[Nat]) .
    eq f(nil) = nil .
endm
```

Just the straightforward recursive solution. Saved a couple bytes by inlining the type in `X:[Nat]` rather than declaring it with the `var` keyword. Doing the same with `A` and `B` doesn't change the byte count — just the way the math works out.

Answer (score 1):

## [Icon](https://github.com/gtownsend/icon), 47 bytes

```
procedure f(L)
L[i:=1to*L by 2]:=:L[i+1]&\z
end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0zOz/v/v6AoPzk1pbQoVSFNw0eTyyc608rWsCRfy0chqVLBKNbK1goopG0YqxZTxZWal4KkPjcxM09Dk0sBCBIVrGwVog11jHSMdUx0THXMYsHCaRqJEPnUstSiSoXyosySVA1FoBjIIAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), 10 bytes

**Solution:**

```
,/|:'0N 2#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/X0e/xkrdwE/BSNlQwUjBWMFEwVTB7P9/AA)

**Explanation:**

```
,/|:'0N 2# / the solution
     0N 2# / reshape into n x 2 grid
  |:'      / reverse (|:) each (')
,/         / flatten
```

**Alternatives:**

- `,/+|+0N 2#` - also **10 bytes**

Comment: You can switch to [ngn/k](https://bitbucket.org/ngn/k) for 9 bytes: `,/|'0N 2#`

Answer (score 1):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), <s>49</s> 47 bytes

```
proc S L {lmap a\ b $L {lappend M $b $a}
set M}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYo7DsIwEER7n@Ip8gEIv4IzkCploDAhBVJwVsSpVnt2YxKK0bx5mtSPOctn6mm5ouM7COHGA/9bQWSITxp8EcHcPCQay@srok5r9hw4cuJsTnfUlJgzVJY084oXt4KPW09L@puuLfK@cVVZ/gI)

Answer (score 1):

## MMIX, 40 bytes (10 instrs)

Assumes 8-byte size for list elements.

`void __mmixware swao(uint64_t *l, size_t len)`

hexdump (jxd -T):

```
00000000: 42010009 3f010101 27010101 8fff0000  B¢¡µ?¢¢¢'¢¢¢Ɓ”¡¡
00000010: 8f020008 afff0008 af020000 e7000010  Ɓ£¡®Ḥ”¡®Ḥ£¡¡ḃ¡¡Ñ
00000020: 5b01fffa f8000000                    [¢”«ẏ¡¡¡
```

Disassembled:

```
swae    BZ   $1,1F          // if nothing, return
        SRU  $1,$1,1        // turn length into loop count
0H      SUBU $1,$1,1        // decrement loop count
        LDOU $255,$0,0      // load l[0]
        LDOU $2,$0,8        // load l[1]
        STOU $255,$0,8      // store the other way
        STOU $2,$0,0        // store the other way
        INCL $0,16          // l += 2
        PBNZ $1,0B          // if loop count isn't yet 0, loop back
1H      POP  0,0            // return
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) + `-p`, 8 bytes

This sets `$_` (implicitly `print`ed by `-p`) to the next line of STDIN (`<>` - which isn't trimmed via `chomp`) concatenated with the current line (`$_`).

```perl
$_=<>.$_
```

[Try it online!](https://dom111.github.io/code-sandbox/#eyJsYW5nIjoid2VicGVybC01LjI4LjEiLCJjb2RlIjoiJF89PD4uJF8iLCJhcmdzIjoiLXAiLCJpbnB1dCI6IjFcbjJcbjNcbjRcbjVcbjZcbiJ9)

or (with `-nl -M5.10.0`):

```perl
say<>.$_
```

[Try it online!](https://dom111.github.io/code-sandbox/#eyJsYW5nIjoid2VicGVybC01LjI4LjEiLCJjb2RlIjoic2F5PD4uJF8iLCJhcmdzIjoiLW5sXG4tTTUuMTAuMCIsImlucHV0IjoiMVxuMlxuM1xuNFxuNVxuNlxuIn0=)

---

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) + `-p -M5.10.0`, 8 bytes

This outputs (`say`) the next line of STDIN (`<>`), after converting to a number (`$-=`) to avoid the trailing newline, then the current line is output via `-p`.

```perl
say$-=<>
```

[Try it online!](https://dom111.github.io/code-sandbox/#eyJsYW5nIjoid2VicGVybC01LjI4LjEiLCJjb2RlIjoic2F5JC09PD4iLCJhcmdzIjoiLXBcbi1NNS4xMC4wIiwiaW5wdXQiOiIxXG4yXG4zXG40XG41XG42In0=)

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia](https://julialang.org)

### 25 bytes

```
!x=x[1:end.|>i->i-(-1)^i]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=NY-9CsIwFIX3PEXEpYHb0h8rUklxzVIXnUKFgClWpJU2BQcfwt2lSx_CR-nbeJsqJOSe850DN-_h2t1K1Y-vszKKS0KpDCCECFYQwzrnqQwhQBHBGuIcJu6jgXdidgDf-o2-a2UcaXXEePo3piwaQHKypKqqzUU3tK50gnLx4A_pCB4kujpvd55wHTdgJ8HyoTOFu_nYgKXeMy1dPDZQ_vjISFE31BEZ7I8Hxqdf4C471ba6MXQhMs4REOzPhb6f3y8)

### 24 bytes

```
!x=x[(I=1:end).-(-1).^I]
```

Answer (score 1):

## [ECMAScript 2015](https://262.ecma-international.org/6.0/) with [Lodash](https://lodash.com/) (Array), 39 bytes

```js
l=>_.chunk(l,2).flatMap(s=>[s[1],s[0]])
```

Solution below works if array doesn't chunk evenly (`l.length % 2 == 1`)

```js
l=>_.chunk(l,2).flatMap(s=>s.length-1?[s[1],s[0]]:s)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), <s>37</s> 30 bytes

```arturo
$=>[map&[a,b]->@[b,a]|flatten]
```

[Try it](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?F6AEju)

Answer (score 1):

### Prolog - 36 bytes

```
s([],[]).s([A,B|L],[B,A|R]):-s(L,R).
```

Non code-golf:

```
;; swap empty list is empty list
swap([],[]).

;; swap of A,B followed by L is B,A followed by R, where swap(L,R).
swap([A,B|L],[B,A|R]):-swap(L,R).
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 39 bytes

```python
f=lambda x:x and[x.pop(~len(x)%2)]+f(x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/P802JzE3KSVRocKqQiExLyW6Qq8gv0CjLic1T6NCU9VIM1Y7Dcj4X2EbbahjpGOsY6JjqmMWa11QlJlXApSwrrIFyUP5VZpcYIUGOkCMW9F/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Whitespace](https://web.archive.org/web/20150618184706/http://compsoc.dur.ac.uk/whitespace/tutorial.php), 131 bytes

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72qPCOzJLW4IDE5dcGCpaUlaboWN5sVFBQ4Fbg4uTg5oSw4A0QAWVxAEsZBKERiAAGXAkSTAkQJlMYhAdQCMZaTiwtsE8QpUBctWGnCZchlxGXMZQIRAAA)

Generated from the following asm2ws program:

```
2 / GETN / 2 / RCL / 2 / DIV
@LOOP
    DUP / BZ %END
    0 / GETN
    1 / GETN
    1 / RCL / PUTN
    32 / PUTC
    0 / RCL / PUTN
    32 /PUTC
    1 / SUB / B %LOOP
@END
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 16 [bits<sup>v2</sup>](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyncode/blob/main/README.md), 2 bytes

```
2ẇR
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2&c=1#WyJBPSIsIiIsIjLhuodSIiwiIiwiWzEsMiwzLDQsNSw2XVxuWzAsMSwwLDFdIl0=)

Bitstring:

```
0100011100000110
```

another 2 byter

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 48 bytes

```python
f=lambda l:l[::-1][:2]+f(l[2:])if len(l)>1else l
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P802JzE3KSVRIccqJ9rKStcwNtrKKFY7TSMn2sgqVjMzTSEnNU8jR9POMDWnOFUh5/9/AA)

Very simple. For some reason l[:2:-1] doesn't work.

Comment: [Fail](https://tio.run/##BcExDoAgDADArzDSWAdAHZroR0gHjBBJKhJl8fV4V7923sX1nlYJ134EJSSeaDTsyfKQtHhLDDkpiUULbCbKG5X0@uTSdNLeoEWHE864MED/AQ)