# Remove odd indices and double the even indices

Tags: code-golf, string, array

Your task is simple, just remove the odd indices and double the even indices

### Example

the input is `Hello, World!` and we get indices

```
H e l l o , _ W o r  l  d  !
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13
```

and remove the odd indices

```
el,Wrd
```

Double!

```
eell,,WWrrdd
```

and you are done

1-Indexing

### Test cases

```
abcdef => bbddff
umbrella => mmrrllaa
looooooooong text => ooooooooooggttxx
abc => bb
xkcd => kkdd
Hello, World! => eell,,WWrrdd
D => <empty>
KK => KK
Hi => ii
odd_length! => dd__eegghh
<empty> => <empty>
```

The input can be list if you want.

Comment: Can we use zero-indexed?

Comment: @BgilMidol No you can't

Comment: Can we return as the form of [(n, n), (n, n), ...]?

Comment: No, array depth must be 1

Comment: Can we assume input is not empty?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 3 bytes

```
y2•
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCJ5MuKAoiIsIiIsInVtYnJlbGxhIl0=)

Vyxal has a better built-in for this than Jelly.

```
y2•     Full Program
y       Uninterleave; push a[::2] and a[1::2]
 2•     Repeat each character twice
```

Comment: Taking input as a list of characters allows this to be just `yd`

Answer (score 17):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 8 bytes

```
,,[..,,]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fRydaT09HJ/b///yUlPic1Lz0kgxFAA)

Comment: That's some elegant procedural programming.

Comment: `,[,..,]` is shorter and it works

Comment: @okie That prints two trailing zero bytes for inputs of odd length

Answer (score 11):

## [convey](http://xn--wxa.land/convey/), 8 bytes

*-1 thanks to Wheat Wizard!*

```
v2{
0"!}
```

[Try it online!](https://xn--wxa.land/convey/run.html#eyJjIjoidjJ7XG4wXCIhfSIsInYiOjEsImkiOiInSGVsbG8sIFdvcmxkIScifQ==)

[image: example run]

The 0 and 2 loop around, applying themselves to the input via `!` (take), thus duping the element 0 or 2 times.

Comment: [8 bytes](https://xn--wxa.land/convey/run.html#eyJjIjoidjJ7XG4wXCIhfSIsInYiOjEsImkiOiInSGVsbG8sIFdvcmxkIScifQ==)

Answer (score 10):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 8 bytes

```
#~0 2$~#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/lesMFIxU6pT/a3KlJmfkK6QpqHuk5uTk6yiE5xflpCiqw4UrspNT1P8DAA)

- `0 2$~#` Repeat the pattern `0 2` for the length of the string:

  ```
  Hello, World
  020202020202
  ```
- `#~` Use that mask to "copy" the characters: zeros get deleted, twos get doubled:

  ```
  eell,,WWrrdd
  ```

Answer (score 6):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>35</s> <s>34</s> 32 bytes

*Edit: -1 byte thanks to Giuseppe*

```r
function(x)rep(x,`[<-`(x,0:1*2))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jc@9TsMwFAXgPU9hymJXqQRMCLWdGKiyFmVgSJPca8eKfyrrBpmnD2YAV0z2YulY35FPWAPazgN0MJgOP91hlYsbSXvHowh45bG@fOx3l3Q/vDxun4RYtaOzfyf5zP9ZvqTw7E@O@KYfRkC5EUKwe3Y4smEAkLIqsosdAhrTZ21tCCnoy7zxv8cpRhgpF/29eKWIYqxKx9wuKUNxHiGreQYoc29puq9Z64OBu1yAKa7rtg2htOg14z3aK30dy1zTZNg0hZ/W2WhdZn5ig07RdDMzZR2iUtNUrd8)

Comment: Use `!1:0` as the index.

Comment: @Giuseppe - I tried a bit, but couldn't make the "```D```" test-case work...  am I missing something?

Comment: No, you're right. R has such annoying length-1 special cases. I suppose a minor improvement would be `!seq(!x)%%2` then.

Comment: I think you can switch to a newer version of R (I think it's 4.1) and get this down to [25 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=jZK9TsMwFEYlRp7CLYuNUgmYItR26gDKWpQBpDTuvXai-KeyXGSehSUM7Ky8Ck-DUQSumOzlSt_1OfIn-fXNjR8OdWMBGuCqwWezej96sSg_n2hgDg80FLvH5WIX59Xt9eUNY9P-60z2xm_tgxcl_aeg8Ua5tffG03nL94BizhgjF2S1JpwDCHGexR41d6hUm2itnYtBm8cr-3uMJB6DT6K_jZXS-xDyhLHMaZM8KAx7SNQwAORxd7G6LUhtnYJZEmCMi6KuncsVbRK8RH3wL-s8rqoSWFWZj-4T0_d5zE-s0EjfndSMWYMoZddN_20cp_kN). (I have no experience in R, and I just saw this trick [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421088/18746959)...)

Comment: @TheThonnu - You're right, of course, but I (and many of the other R golfers) am generally happy to ignore the ```function```/```\``` choice if it's just a case of 7-bytes with no other inventiveness.  Sometimes using the less-expensive ```\``` notation favours or allows fundamentally different approaches, which makes it worthwhile, but here it would (to me) just feel a little 'cheap' to change it...

Comment: @TheThonnu - (and its not uncommon to restrict an answer to ```function``` or ```\``` just to compete with whatever the other R golfers used already, just to make a 'fair' competition: see [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/248972/iterative-smallest-complement/248975#comment556226_248975) for example...)

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jellylanguage), 4 bytes

```
Ḋm2Ḥ
```

[Try It Online!](https://jht.hyper-neutrino.xyz/tio#WyIiLCLhuIptMuG4pCIsIiIsIiIsWyJ1bWJyZWxsYSJdXQ==)

```
Ḋm2Ḥ    Main Link
Ḋ       Remove the first character
 m2     Return every other character
   Ḥ    Double. This turns ["a", "b"] into ["aa", "bb"], which
        is not the correct format for a Jelly string, but displays
        correctly when printed.
```

Comment: There really ought to be a builtin for `m2`

Comment: Almost a three byte monadic Link by abusing how `sparse` is implemented [TIO](https://tio.run/##BcGxDYAwDATAVb6DGegZxIoNEYpi5DgSrEDFOPRMwiTmbpNSzojvud5bI2I@3Agpk1FyMRCzMFwhlRt0gTKjSF09Dw1JzSQ5tPveHdP4Aw) :(

Answer (score 5):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 37 bytes

```
lambda a:"".join(x*2for x in a[1::2])
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweI025ilpSVpuhY3VXMSc5NSEhUSrZSU9LLyM_M0KrSM0vKLFCoUMvMUEqMNrayMYjWhinUKijLzSjTSNJRKc5OKUnNyEpU0NbnggvkpKfE5qXnpJRmKQHGIngULIDQA)

Answer (score 5):

## [ayr](https://github.com/ZippyMagician/ayr), <s>9</s> 8 bytes

Using Jonah's J method gets me -1 byte

```
]#0 2$`#
```

I have the advantage of `#`'s args being swapped compared to J, but unfortunately monadic 2-trains are not hooks like in J.
Old answer:

```
:,_2]/,@:
```

[Try it!](https://zippymagician.github.io/ayr#Zjo@/XSMwIDIkYCM@/PWYiICdIZWxsbywgV29ybGQhJyAnYWJjZGVmJyAndW1icmVsbGEn//)

## Explained

`:` is partial application (K-style train)

```
     ,@:   Zip-self with concatenation
 _2]/      Split into groups of two, take right element
,          Flatten
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 5 bytes

```
Ṙ2Ċ2t
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//@HOGUZHuoxK/v//75Gak5OvoxCeX5SToggA)

#### Explanation

```
Ṙ2Ċ2t
    t   drop first char
  Ċ2    take every 2-nd char
Ṙ2      repeat each char 2 times
```

Comment: Alternative 5-byter: ```Ṙ¢Θ;2```

Answer (score 5):

## [Uiua](https://www.uiua.org/), 7 bytes

```
▽↯△,0_2
```

[Try it online!](https://www.uiua.org/pad?src=ZiDihpAg4pa94oav4pazLDBfMgoKZiAiSGVsbG8sIFdvcmxkISI=)

```
▽↯△,0_2    input: a string
  ↯△,0_2    [0, 2] cycled to the length of the input:
      0_2      [0, 2]
   △,         shape of the input ([length])
  ↯            reshape [0, 2] to the shape [length]
▽           keep; delete chars at 0s and duplicate at 2s
```

Comment: Nice idea to reshape 0_2

Answer (score 4):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `sequences.repeating`, 19 bytes

```
[ <odds> 2 repeat ]
```

Get the odd-indexed elements then repeat them twice.

[image]

Comment: @Fmbalbuena I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: @Fmbalbuena Okay, done, but why?

Answer (score 4):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 29 bytes

```javascript
x=>x.replace(/.(.?)/g,'$1$1')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYzNTsQgFEb3PEVNJikY7Ni1tm6MmaRLF102FC4US6FSxjAxPnuF8YfN/e75uOeNfbCNe72GO@sE7LLZY9PGysNqGAd8rHD1RI6Klof6UJdkf0Ae3s/aAy7lVpL0kYkXbeD1Yjm@p6VhQdv6WvwacHVLiqYt8kwiPFBGR9K0n9zZzRmojFM4ISoxI@SL7GzkAmQ@GUchpETnZfRgDMtoWbxPkSHj/p5VRYAYcvvPnFIhxIiS60eE4sxFjvMsBDolnaNF77wRN5lCApT2vfepfc7kEZY1XFrUdXnrOnTSOWiNnBCDAavCdD1N2wCg1DR9Aw)

Answer (score 4):

## Excel, 46 bytes

```
=CONCAT(REPT(MID(A1,SEQUENCE(2^15,,2,2),1),2))
```

Input is in cell `A1`. Output is wherever the formula is.

Working from the inside out:

- `SEQUENCE(2^15,,2,2)` creates an array of even numbers from 2 to 32,768. This is the [limit](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3) for how many characters can be in a cell so it's the limit of the input.
- `MID(A1,SEQUENCE(~),1)` pulls out all the even-index characters one at a time.
- `REPT(MID(~),2)` doubles all those characters.
- `CONCAT(REPT(~))` combines them all into a single string.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: `=LET(a,MID(A1,2*ROW(1:16384),1),CONCAT(a&a))` for 44 or `=CONCAT(REPT(MID(A1,2*ROW(1:16384),1),2))` for 41

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
ιθºS
```

I/O as a list of characters.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//3M5zOw7tCv7/P1rJQ0lHKRWIc6A4H4hBUAGIw6H8IqhcChArKsUCAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9TVmmvpPCobZKCkn1l8P9zO8/tOLQr@L@Xzv/EpOSU1DSu0tykotScnESunHwYyEtXKEmtKOECquCqyE5O4fIAKsjXUQjPL8pJUeRy4fL25vLI5MpPSYnPSc1LL8lQBAA).

**Explanation:**

```python
ι     # Uninterleave the (implicit) input-list into two parts
      #  e.g. ["a","b","c","d","e","f"] → [["a","c","e"],["b","d","f"]]
 θ    # Only leave the last/second part
      #  → ["b","d","f"]
  º   # Mirror/double each character
      #  → ["bb","dd","ff"]
   S  # Convert the list of strings to a flattened list of characters
      #  → ["b","b","d","d","f","f"]
      # (after which it is output implicitly as result)
```

Comment: `ºS` could alternatively also be `€D`, which duplicates each item while still remaining a flattened list.

Answer (score 3):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 10 bytes

```
.(.?)
$1$1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P9fT0PPXpNLxVDF8P//xKTklNQ0rtLcpKLUnJxErpx8GMhLVyhJrSjhAqrgqshOTuHyACrI11EIzy/KSVHkcuHy9ubyyOTKT0mJz0nNSy/JUAQA) Link includes test cases. Explanation: Port of @l4m2's JavaScript answer. In Retina 1 you can write `2*$1` for the same byte count.

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 8 bytes

```
⭆Ｓ×ι⊗﹪κ²
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRCO4BEil@yYWaHjmFZSWQLgamjoKIZm5qcUamToKLvmlSTmpKRq@@SmlOfka2ToKRpogYP3/v0dqTk6@jkJ4flFOiiLXf92yHAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
 Ｓ          Input as a string
⭆           Map over characters and join
   ι        Current character
  ×         Repeated by
      κ     Current index
     ﹪      Modulo
       ²    Literal integer `2`
    ⊗       Doubled
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) -p, 14 bytes

```perl
s/.(.?)/$1$1/g
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/79YX09Dz15TX8VQxVA//f//xKTklNQ0rtLcpKLUnJxErpx8GMhLVyhJrSjhAqrgqshOTuHyACrI11EIzy/KSVHkcuHy9ubyyOTKT0mJz0nNSy/JUPyXX1CSmZ9X/F@3AAA)

Comment: Uses the `-p` flag, for those of you not brave enough to click on the link.

Answer (score 3):

## [BQN](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/), 9 bytes<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/mlochbaum/BQN/blob/master/commentary/sbcs.bqn)</sup>

```
⊢/˜≠⥊0‿2˙
```

[Run online!](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=RiDihpAg4oqiL8uc4omg4qWKMOKAvzLLmQoKUyDihpAgKCjiiqIty5wrYMOXwqwp4oiYPeKKlOKKoikKPijiiqLii4jCt0Ygwq8x4oaTwrfiipEnPSfiirhTKcKoKEArMTApIFMgImFiY2RlZiA9PiBiYmRkZmYKdW1icmVsbGEgPT4gbW1ycmxsYWEKbG9vb29vb29vb25nIHRleHQgPT4gb29vb29vb29vb2dndHR4eAphYmMgPT4gYmIKeGtjZCA9PiBra2RkCkhlbGxvLCBXb3JsZCEgPT4gZWVsbCwsV1dycmRkCkQgPT4gPGVtcHR5PgpLSyA9PiBLSwpIaSA9PiBpaQpvZGRfbGVuZ3RoISA9PiBkZF9fZWVnZ2hoCiA9PiA8ZW1wdHk+Ig==)

Uses Jonah's J idea.

## [BQN](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/), 10 bytes<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/mlochbaum/BQN/blob/master/commentary/sbcs.bqn)</sup>

```
2/1⊑˘⌊‿2⊸⥊
```

[Run online!](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=RiDihpAgMi8x4oqRy5jijIrigL8y4oq44qWKCgpTIOKGkCAoKOKKoi3LnCtgw5fCrCniiJg94oqU4oqiKQo+KOKKouKLiMK3RiDCrzHihpPCt+KKkSc9J+KKuFMpwqgoQCsxMCkgUyAiYWJjZGVmID0+IGJiZGRmZgp1bWJyZWxsYSA9PiBtbXJybGxhYQpsb29vb29vb29vbmcgdGV4dCA9PiBvb29vb29vb29vZ2d0dHh4CmFiYyA9PiBiYgp4a2NkID0+IGtrZGQKSGVsbG8sIFdvcmxkISA9PiBlZWxsLCxXV3JyZGQKRCA9PiA8ZW1wdHk+CktLID0+IEtLCkhpID0+IGlpCm9kZF9sZW5ndGghID0+IGRkX19lZWdnaGgKID0+IDxlbXB0eT4i)

Answer (score 3):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 28 bytes

```javascript
f=([,y,...z])=>y?y+y+f(z):''
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYxNbsMgEIX3nGK6MiiUAzQi3aRSJB/AiyRKsPkxNTYWppGdqmd3IVU6QsOb7828T3ETUxPsGF8HL9WqeXr4SBfKGLufCd8t78tm2Wh8J29FsUbgcEWibqTSwHdQ11Jqjb76OijnREZ9H0KSAjn/rMFAVHPM7j/zxsQ4zznrLwjNXSOz7Dop0SHFeQqVD06@ZKoSoLSqQkjuPhNUlvkrS3SwWViLvJQXpwYT28dNmi5KGdO26MpisD0mbBqdjbg4DQVhvRixy4vuifNQELJFkWkfPkTTYny0FNSZZOsbATR@mLxTzHmDFXAOGltCHz3d/ZDt@gs)

Comment: [28](https://tio.run/##PYxNboMwEIX3PsV0E2zh@gKRs2qlSByABUWJwT@4GIyMW0Gqnj21W6WjkebN92beu/gUax/sEp9nL9Vd89S4oTtljN1awk/Nfjjs5V5qfCPtPQKHKxJdL5UGfoKuk1Jr9DF1QTknMpqmEJIUyPlHzQai2mJ2/5k3JsZty1l/QWgbe5nlOEqJzinOU6h9cPIpU5UApXUdQnJfMkFVlUdVobPNwlrkpbw4NZs4/P6k7aKUMcOAriwGO2HC1sXZiIu3uSBsEgt2@dA9cF4KQo4oMu3Dq@gHjBtLQbUkW18IoPfz6p1izhusgHPQ2BIKRVFmkV6/yfH@Aw)

Answer (score 3):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 10 bytes

```
(2*2!!#:)#
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJxlkFFPgzAUhd/vr2DMB2dgRGI0Ad3THpbwA/awLBu0l9JQ6Czd0sXob7e1Q6fyQO45597T5Kuz2/QunUym2WwKoLO3m835Q2V1EAQm38s2v93XJRe5yc+5mm3fQW/CsiIU6zAPq4rSug63zjx2lUIhSmt3nVJ2Kn0g5Pj1LNBotN34tiRjWhvjN23vV6lXpiXUyral1BsrWy+jYC2VoBOboNVRtF4rddmIwqW1/XJR2NH+/CW3gnMvJKU7gT3TjSuxYofIWNP41Bck0Gh9GLIkIZIik6KeD7okLRrSlD3DOZFd8nrEQXPZD0n6cJ8+PiUKO3nC2D4Q855ygkNc9jSm8lgJjHWDMZ6wHzMAzzF4WQQeJIwMnTVChH/8XPoXoOvyReC4udGBg1/MnHsNDZbOecbuoM8LKAqnigJW3A2cwxUp5/yggsvN1fknfze9SQ==)

- `(...)#` set up a filter/replicate, where the code in `(...)` is run on the (implicit) input and returns a list of numbers. for each such number, that many copies of the corresponding input item will be returned.
- `(2*2!!#:)` return a sequence like `0 2 0 2 ... 0 2` that matches the length of the input. this removes items at even indices (0-based), and doubles those at odd indices

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 23 bytes

```hs
f(a:b:c)=b:b:f c
f _=[]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfmfm5iZp2CrkJlXklqUmFyikPY/TSPRKskqWdM2CUilKSRzpSnE20bH/v/vAVSfr6MQnl@Uk6IIAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 53 bytes

```
func[s][foreach c extract/index s 2 2[prin c prin c]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0pN@R@UmhIdy5Vm9T@tNC85ujg2Oi2/KDUxOUMhWSG1oqQoMblEPzMvJbVCoVjBSMEouqAoMw8oBaFiY/@nKSh5pObk5OsohOcX5aQoKv0HAA)

`extract/index s 2 2` says "get every other element of `s` starting at index 2" (keeping in mind Red is 1-indexed). Then print each of those elements twice.

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 35 bytes

```c
f(char*c){for(;*c++;c++)c[-1]=*c;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@r5yZl5xTmpJqU1ySkpmvl2H3P00jOSOxSCtZszotv0jDWitZW9saiDWTo3UNY221kq1ruf7nJmbmaWhWgxQqJEfH2ip5pObk5OsohOcX5aQoKlkDzdC0LijKzCsBs2r/AwA)

Comment: [31 bytes](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9NIzkjsUgrWbM6Lb9Iw1or2VpbO1lTK1lb2xbIrv2fm5iZp6FZDVKkkBwda6vkkZqTk6@jEJ5flJOiqGQN1K9pXVCUmVcCZtX@/5eclpOYXvxftxwA)

Comment: This answer overwrites past the end of the array if its length is odd (unless you're lucky and there are two null bytes in a row), which seems wrong.

Answer (score 2):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 4 bytes

```
i#o:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/P1M53@r///yUlPic1Lz0kgxFAA)

Terminates with an error.

[This again?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/237085/swap-every-two-elements-in-a-list/237115#237115)

### How?

```
i     Take an input (instruction pointer (IP) going right)
 #    IP bounces off # and starts going left
i     Take another input
   :  Duplicate it
  o   Output it
 #    IP bounces off # and starts going right
  o   Output again
   :  Duplicate (Useless)

And now, we're back to where we started, at the first character facing right.
The code will continue executing until it terminates with an error when running out of input.
```

Answer (score 2):

## [GNU AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), 35 bytes

```
BEGIN{RS=".|"}{printf NR%2?e:RT RT}
```

or

```
BEGIN{RS=".|";ORS=e}$0=NR%2?e:RT RT
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v/fydXd0686KNhWSa9Gqba6oCgzryRNwS9I1cg@1SooRCEopJZLGUWRtT@QkVqrYmCLrIpLubggJ7NEQ8VAJ1EnVbM6Lb9II1MhM08hURNqZiZYcWJ0ZiwI1/7/75Gak5OvoxCeX5SToggA)

This is possible thanks to the `RT` variable, only available in GNU AWK. The characters are stored one at a time in `RT`, and the ternary conditional operator is used to skip the odds and double the even characters.

## AWK, 47 bytes

```
split($0,a,e){for(i in a)printf i%2?e:a[i]a[i]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v9f2cnV3dOvOijYVkmvRqm2uqAoM68kTcEvSNXIPtUqKEQhKKSWC1WRtT@QkVqrYmCLrIqruCAns0RDxUAnUSdVszotv0gjUyEzTyFRE2pkJlhtYnRmLAjX/v/vkZqTk6@jEJ5flJOiCAA)

Splits the input character by characters into the array `a`, and does the skip-and-double magic through the ternary operator `?:`.

Answer (score 2):

### **[MATLAB](https://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab.html), 25 bytes**

```
@(x)repelem(x(2:2:end),2)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org/),<strike>77</strike> 83 bytes

Edited to comply with code golf rules. Assumes at least a space in input because I'm not entirely sure how to make it work with nil input without throwing an error.

```lua
p,t=io.read(),{} for i=0,#p,2 do t[i],t[i+1]=string.sub(p,i,i),string.sub(p,i,i)end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yylN/P@/QKfENjNfryg1MUVDU6e6ViEtv0gh09ZAR7lAx0ghJV@hJDozVgdIaBvG2haXFGXmpesVlyZpFOhk6mRq6mCIpOal/P//HwA)

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, and nice answer!

Comment: [Welcome to Code Golf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20861/66833), and nice first answer! Unfortunately, assuming input and output is in a variable in not an [accepted method of I/O](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods)

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing Should be fixed now

Answer (score 2):

## [Fig](https://github.com/Seggan/Fig), \$4\log_{256}(96)\approx\$ 3.292 bytes

```
eh]y
```

[Try it online!](https://fig.fly.dev/#WyJlaF15IiwiYWJjZGVmIl0=)

### Explanation

```
eh]y
   y   Uninterleave the input - return a list like [a[::2], a[1::2]]
  ]    Get the last element (which is a[1::2])
e      Over each character...
 h     Double it
```

Comment: Can you explain it?

Comment: @Fmbalbuena Sure, done

Answer (score 2):

## [4](https://github.com/urielieli/py-four), 25 bytes

```
3.72372382352352372372394
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##M/n/31jP3MgYiCyMjE3BCMK1NMEjBQA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
zt2Ḅ
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faMGCpaUlaboWy6pKjB7uaFlSnJRcDBVasNYjNScnX0chPL8oJ0URIggA)

##### Explanation

```python
zt2Ḅ  # Implicit input
z     # Uninterleave
 t    # Leave only the tail
  2Ḅ  # Double each character
      # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Coconut](http://coconut-lang.org/), 40 bytes

```
"".join(map(->_*2,input()[1::2]))`print`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85Pzs8rLfn/X0lJLys/M08jN7FAQ9cuXstIJzOvoLREQzPa0MrKKFZTM6GgKDOvJOH///yUlPic1Lz0kgxFAA)

I'm just learning Coconut, so there's probably a shorter, better way to do this...  Feedback 100% welcomed!

Here's how it works:

```
            ->_*2                        - def lambda that dup's a char
                  input()                - read string from STDIN
                         [1::2]          - make a list of even num chars
        map(    ,              )         - map the lambda over char list
"".join(                        )        - convert list to a string
                                 `print` - apply "print" implicit lambda
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org), 8 [bytes](https://www.uiua.org/pad?src=U0JDUyDihpAgK0BcMOKKlwpEZWNvZGUg4oaQIOKHjOKKjy0x4pa9wrEu4o2Y4ouv4oav4oqCwq8x4qe74ouv4qe7LOKHjOKItSjihpjCrzHii68rMjU2KSAtQFwwKzEKJnAg4oqCIjggYml0IGVuY29kaW5nOlx0IiBTQkNTICLih4ziio8tMeKWvcKxLuKNmOKLr-KGr-KKgsKvMeKnu-KLr-Knuyzih4ziiLUo4oaYwq8x4ouvKzI1NikiIOKKgitAXDDih6ExMjkiLiziiLY74oiYwqzCscKv4oy14oia4peL4oyK4oyI4oGFPeKJoDziiaQ-4omlKy3Dl8O34pe_4oG_4oKZ4oan4oal4oig4qe74paz4oeh4oqi4oeM4pmt4ouv4o2J4o2P4o2W4oqa4oqb4oqd4pah4oqU4omF4oqf4oqC4oqP4oqh4oav4oaZ4oaY4oa74per4pa94oyV4oiK4oqXL-KIp1xc4oi14omh4oi64oqe4oqg4o2l4oqV4oqc4oip4oqT4oqD4oqZ4ouF4o2Y4o2c4o2a4qyaJz_ijaPijaQh4o6L4oas4pqCzrfPgM-E4oiefl9bXXt9KCnCr0AkXCLihpB8IyIKJnAg4oqCImRlY29kZWQ6XHQiIERlY29kZSAiwqPCsS0xwrjChy7DjMKlwrPCsMKIMcKfwqXCnyzCo8K_KMK1wogxwqUrMjU2KSIg4oqCK0BcMOKHoTEyOSIuLOKItjviiJjCrMKxwq_ijLXiiJril4vijIrijIjigYU94omgPOKJpD7iiaUrLcOXw7fil7_igb_igpnihqfihqXiiKDip7vilrPih6HiiqLih4zima3ii6_ijYnijY_ijZbiipriipviip3ilqHiipTiiYXiip_iioLiio_iiqHihq_ihpnihpjihrvil6vilr3ijJXiiIriipcv4oinXFziiLXiiaHiiLriip7iiqDijaXiipXiipziiKniipPiioPiipnii4XijZjijZzijZrirJonP-KNo-KNpCHijovihqzimoLOt8-Az4TiiJ5-X1tde30oKcKvQCRcIuKGkHwjIg==)

```
▽+.◿2⇡⧻.
```

[Try it!](https://uiua.org/pad?src=ZiDihpAg4pa9Ky7il78y4oeh4qe7LgoKZiAiYWJjZGVmIgpmICJhYmNkZSIKZiAiYWIiCmYgImEiCmYgImFhYWEiCmYgImEgYiI=)

```
▽+.◿2⇡⧻.
       .  # duplicate
      ⧻   # length
     ⇡    # range
   ◿2     # modulo two
 +.       # double
▽         # keep
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), <s>9</s> 8 bytes

```
S*<>aX:2
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724ILNgwYKlpSVpuhYrgrVs7BIjrIwgXKjoxmglj9ScnHwdhfD8opwURaVYqAQA)

#### Explanation

```lisp
    a    ; Command-line argument
  <>     ; Break into two-character substrings
S*       ; Remove the first character of each
     X:2 ; Double each
         ; Concatenate together and output (implicit)
```

If the argument string has an odd number of characters, the final substring created by `<>` will have one character in it. `S` will remove that one character, leaving the empty string. Doubling the empty string and concatenating it to the output does not affect the output.

Answer (score 2):

## [Nekomata](https://github.com/AlephAlpha/Nekomata), 3 bytes

```
ĭ:Ĭ
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70iLzU7PzexJHFZtJJurlLsgqWlJWm6FkuPrLU6smZJcVJyMVRkwc1kpcSk5JTUNCUupdLcpKLUnJxEIDMnHwby0hVKUitKgGJAdUCyIjs5BUh5ABXm6yiE5xflpCgC-S5A7O0NksgEEvkpKfE5qXnpJRkgOSWIXQA)

```
ĭ:Ĭ
ĭ   Uninterleave
 :  Duplicate
  Ĭ Interleave
```

Answer (score 1):

## APL+WIN, <s>15</s> 14 bytes

-1 byte thanks to Adám

Prompts for string

```
2/(~2|⍳⍴m)/m←⍞
```

[Try it online! Thanks to Dyalog Classic](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v@ob6qvz6O2CcZcQJanP5BlyPWooz3tv5G@Rp1RzaPezY96t@Rq6ucCZR71zvsPlOP6n8aVmJSckprGlcZVmptUlJqTkwhk5uTDQF66QklqRQkXWB2QrMhOTgFSHkCF@ToK4flFOSmKQL4LEHt7gyQygUR@Skp8TmpeekmGIgA)

Comment: Use `⍞` instead of `⎕` so the user doesn't need to deal with quotes and `'a'` being a scalar. Then you certainly don't need `,`

Comment: @Adám Thanks. Done.

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 13 bytes

```apl
{2/⍵/⍨~2|⍳≢⍵}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qKM97X@1kf6j3q1AvKLOqOZR7@ZHnYuA/FqQ5H8FIEjjMuSC0EBJQwMA)

pretty self explnatory

Comment: A translation of my J answer would probably save some bytes.

Answer (score 1):

## [sed 4.2.2](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/), 5 bytes

```
n;p;p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K05N@f8/z7rAuuD//0SuJK5krpR/@QUlmfl5xf918wA)

Takes string input one character per line (if allowed).

- `-n option` Don't print by default
- `n;` Skips a line.
- `p;p` Print the line twice.

### [sed 4.2.2](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/), 15 bytes

```
s/.\(.\)/\1\1/g
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K05N@f@/WF8vRkMvRlM/xjDGUD/9/3@P1JycfB2F8vyinBSuiuzkFAA)

Solution taking a single string.

- `s/.\(.\)/` Substitute any char, followed by any other char...
- `\1\1/` With the 2nd char repeated twice...
- `g` Globally

Comment: [You don't have to add bytes for program flags anymore](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/9481).

Comment: I don't think your second answer works on odd length strings? (Compare @l4m2's JavaScript answer.)

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 12 bytes

```apl
{⍵/⍨0 2⍴⍨≢⍵}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qKM97X/1o96t@o96VxgoGD3q3QJkPOpcBBSqBcn@VwCCNC5DLgj9qHezoQEA)

APL port of @jonah 's j answer

Comment: my bad ,fixed it @jonah

Comment: -1 when written as a train: `⊢⊢⍤/⍨0 2⍴⍨≢`

Comment: I thought you still had to include the braces in a tacid definition @kamila szewczyk

Comment: @JayantChoudhary no, as it can be assigned directly to a var and treated as a function without the braces, which due to how this site handles golfing means you don't need them.

Comment: @JayantChoudhary tacit definitions don't require braces, only parens.

Answer (score 1):

## [naz](https://github.com/sporeball/naz), 40 bytes

```
2x1v1x1f1r3x1v2e1r3x1v2e2o1f0x1x2f0a0x1f
```

It's sure been a while, hasn't it? Works for any null-terminated input string.

[Try it online!](https://sporeball.dev/naz/?code=2x1v1x1f1r3x1v2e1r3x1v2e2o1f0x1x2f0a0x1f&input=Hello%252C%2520World!&n=true)

**Explanation** (with `0x` instructions removed)

```
2x1v                                     # Set variable 1 equal to 0
    1x1f                                 # Function 1
        1r                               # Read a byte of input
          3x1v2e                         # Goto function 2 if it equals variable 1
                1r                       # Read another byte of input
                  3x1v2e                 # Goto function 2 if it equals variable 1
                        2o1f             # Otherwise, output twice and call function 1
                              1x2f       # Function 2
                                  0a     # No-op
                                      1f # Call function 1
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-hP`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), <s>5</s> 4 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

The `¬` can be removed if we can take input as a character array.

```
¬m²ó
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LWhQ&code=rG2y8w&input=IkhlbGxvLCBXb3JsZCEi)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 34 bytes

```python
f=lambda s:s and s[1:2]*2+f(s[2:])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYzNasMwEITveortKXZrCvHRoJ5yCPgBfAjBSFn9YVkSkkzcp3ellHYvO/vNzoTvrL3rj0NSy1aODNKQgDmEdDsP/f29/5BNuvXDvT2e2lgB54GAcaEDv@UAFCJ7zuXectN@pmBNbk5Av@DUEgjRuAyyKXYLlL4SB@MPFLK@cI4oJdlWHoW1rKJ1jbFIRqz/G6cgiz1X9595pXLed1K6fovIvjywymVBJNdS5zuYfLT4VqkooOumKcbiXioh41jXOJKrqcIY4hFnK5zK@pUp1yyEUlr/AA)

Comment: Seems to work for Python 3 just as well.

Answer (score 1):

## [Lexurgy](https://www.lexurgy.com/sc), 32 bytes

Docs [here](https://www.meamoria.com/lexurgy/html/sc-tutorial.html).

Due to Lexurgy's input considering strings as "stuff surrounded by whitespace", no whitespace can appear in the input string. Otherwise, Lexurgy will consider `["Hello, world!"]` as `["Hello,", "world!"]`. Whitespace must be replaced with a different character (such as `_`).

```bash
o:
[] []$1=>* $1 $1
[]=>* /_ $
```

Ungolfed:

```bash
only-evens:
 [] []$1 => * $1 $1 # capture the second character and dup it
 [] => * / _ $ # remove last odd character as well
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 23 bytes

```
#~##&~#&/@#~Drop~;;;;2&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYo/C8IwFMT3foqaQCZFcLWWgh2ELoKDg4q8JukfTBOJTyiI@eqxr@ANd8fvbgDs9ADYS4jNLvLAuQhcrAseSu@eYTtpI@LR9xYvfJWzK2NZ3hT7DjxI1P5V8GymNxFOEmz4JAxqqXTDlgl7D7XXxgB14/6ybYp6RILTlWJ8SEV5mM5umZ6dN2pBoCSrqnnryZ1Sd6Nti928s@Qbfw)

Input a list. Drops odd indices and doubles everything left.

Comment: You can't assume that the input is empty

Comment: @Fmbalbuena I assume you meant non-empty?

Comment: yes, this is what i meant.

Comment: @Fmbalbuena Can you add that to the question please?

Comment: Added, now you can see the last test case.

Answer (score 1):

## [munge](https://github.com/tomtheisen/munge), 20 bytes

```
/.(.)?/=>{$1 $1}
```

[Munge it!](https://munge.netlify.app/#eyJtIjoiLy4oLik/Lz0+eyQxICQxfSIsImkiOiJhYmNkZWZcbnVtYnJlbGxhXG5sb29vb29vb29vbmcgdGV4dFxuYWJjXG54a2NkXG5IZWxsbywgV29ybGQhXG5EXG5LS1xuSGlcbm9kZF9sZW5ndGghXG4ifQ==)

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 32 bytes

```
->s{s.scan(/.(.)/).map{_1*2}*''}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=PVBLToQwGI7b_xSVzcCEYaIrN8zKxSQcgIUaUugDQnmkLQkGOIkbYvRQehr7Q8Yu-j37N-3Hlx7y9_VTxN-DFaenH3K6mMlEpqCtf478KDgHUUP7KXs4Pi7Hw2HZe793gUfzgnFB4gvJc8aEgKHJNVeKotU0WjtKQXW31Upi-Wgx_fc6Ka0dR3Cz9kEw1gVDWteMwdWN60KSdlqxe3S5M8IwTbV26TM6kCQISQLXCklVQcdYpngrbbmdcSrjXMqyBJReZHpVWd97bb39bbOqWj4DQbiFWzMgsEScFuU0W25sqLlxtZ6gAEJj8YLsDS26bXHsKsRRXbUWLwBYYP-xdd3xDw)

Comment: [19 bytes](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/P724NElBX09DT9NeX0c9xlBdy@j/f4/UnJx8HYXw/KKcFMV/@QUlmfl5xf91CwA "Ruby – Try It Online") as a full program (with `-p` flag).

Comment: @Dingus great! You may post your answer, i feel there's too much improvements to be just a suggestion

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) + `-p`, 11 bytes

Takes a list of chars (to differentiate from [@Kjetil's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/241295/9365)).

2 bytes saved thanks to [@Neil](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/17602/neil)!

```perl
$_ x=$|--*2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18lXqHCVqVGV1fL6P9/D65UrhwgzOfS4VLgCgfSRUBeCpfiv/yCksz8vOL/ugUA)

### Explanation

Uses the string repetition operator (`x`) to repeat `$_` `$|--*2` times which, since `$|` can only be `1` or `0`, will alternate between `0` or `2` for each character of input.

Comment: Can you not use `$.%2*2`?

Comment: Ah nice! I can't use that, but I could use `$|--*2`! Thanks!

Comment: Ah, right, the indexing was the wrong way around. You should update your explanation now that you're not using `$.` now though.

Comment: You're right, have done! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

## [SimpleTemplate](https://github.com/ismael-miguel/SimpleTemplate) 0.84, 36 bytes

Requires that an array of characters is passed to the `render()` method in PHP. [Argument unpacking](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#example-159) can be used for convenience. Each argument is 1 character.

```
{@eachargv}{@if__ is mod2}{@echo_,_}
```

This is a full program.

---

### How it works?

It simply loops all over the arguments passed to the `render()` method.

It checks if the index is odd, and, in case it is, displays the character twice.

---

### About the code...

- `{@eachargv}`
  This is a simple loop over the elements in `argv`.
  Automatically, the current value is stored in the variable `_` and the index is stored in `__`.
  A more readable example is `{@each argv as _ key __}`
- `{@if__ is mod2}`
  This checks if the key's [modulo](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php) is a truthy value.
  If it is a truthy value, it means we are dealing with an odd index (the language is 0-indexed, like PHP).
  A readable alternative is `{@if __ is not multiple of 2}`
- `{@echo_,_}`
  Simply outputs the character twice.
- Usually, it would be needed to close the loop and the `if`, but it is optional since there isn't any other code to run outside.

---

You can try this on http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b006b2ec293bab18cd6db2f1b8a2454da047ea49

Please pick PHP 7.4.13.

Answer (score 1):

## [Rattle](https://github.com/DRH001/Rattle), 25 bytes

```
|!I=@[0q][=#%[1=#1g`bb]]@
```

[Try it Online!](https://www.drh001.com/rattle/?flags=&code=%7C!I%3D%40%5B0q%5D%5B%3D%23%25%5B1%3D%231g%60bb%5D%5D%40&inputs=Hello%2C%20World!)

Might not be the most elegant solution...

## Explanation

```
|                  parse input
 !                 disables implicit output (necessary only for special case of empty input)
  I                save input as char array in consecutive memory slots, move pointer to next empty slot
   =@              set top of stack to value of pointer
     [0q]          if the pointer is in the zero position (meaning empty input), terminate the program
         [     ]@  repeat x number of times where x is the value of the pointer (to iterate over all input characters)
      
  =#               set top of stack to current loop iterator
    %              mod 2
     [1       ]    if the result is 1...
       =#1         set top of stack to current loop iterator for main loop
          g`       get value from the memory slot according to the top of the stack
            bb     add char to output buffer twice with no separator
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 6 bytes

```
.i=%2t
```

[Test suite](http://pythtemp.herokuapp.com/?code=.i%3D%252t&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%22abcdef%22%0A%22umbrella%22%0A%22looooooooong+text%22%0A%22abc%22%0A%22xkcd%22%0A%22Hello%2C+World%21%22%0A%22D%22%0A%22KK%22%0A%22Hi%22%0A%22odd_length%21%22%0A%22%22&debug=0). Slightly more interesting one..

**Explanation:**

```
.i=%2t # whole program

       # take the implicit input (Q)
     t # remove the first letter
   %2  # keep the odd indices only
   %2t # keep the even indices only
  =    # assign this to Q (the variable encountered)
.i     # then interleave this, with
       # newly assigned implicit Q (implicit output)
```

---

#### 7 bytes

This one uses a `map` in order to double the characters.

```
s+Rd%2t
```

[Test suite](http://pythtemp.herokuapp.com/?code=s%2BRd%252t&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%22abcdef%22%0A%22umbrella%22%0A%22looooooooong+text%22%0A%22abc%22%0A%22xkcd%22%0A%22Hello%2C+World%21%22%0A%22D%22%0A%22KK%22%0A%22Hi%22%0A%22odd_length%21%22%0A%22%22&debug=0)

Answer (score 1):

## [Rust](https://rust-lang.org), 118 bytes

```rs
fn main(){let y=&mut"".into();std::io::stdin().read_line(y);for(i,c)in(0..).zip(y.chars()){if i%2>0{print!("{c}{c}")}}}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LY5RCsIwEESvUgPKLtRQBUFS9CpS0gQX2rSkKRJDTuJPED2UtzFSYT4ezDAzj5edJ5fSe3Z6e_zctCn6hgxg6JQr_GnTz44xTsYNgPXkWiFoECLDL8StatpLR0aBx1oPFqiUmJ2Kc-R3GsFzeW3sBIiBdEHr_bkKo811K2BBxiyGMcZl_v8iPXeHhb4)

Half is just stdin...

Else,

---

## [Rust](https://rust-lang.org), <s>108</s> <s>106</s> 94 bytes

```rs
|c:&str|{let mut s=format!("");for(i,c)in(0..).zip(c.chars()){if i%2>0{s.push(c);s.push(c)}}s}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=PY1NCsIwFISvEgPKe1BDcSWWehUJoSGB_pGXbExzEjdZ6N6lV_E2VgOu5mOGmbndXSCfn3pkg7QjYOw7z2T7CF7vj-_Lok478m752UPwjFo9uUH6DXCOzcpgK4VrsxYCxdXOoIQy0hEgRquZ3R7OdSQxBzKgsPlTSpSacvOanR2_izHxSgI3Xd9PHDGVOOeiHw)

Comment: I know Rust isn't great for everything...

Comment: You can just use a block instead of a named function to save several bytes: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYxBCsMgEADveYUVWnZBJPRYSf8SbERBjbiGQI1vt8mlt2FgJm9UuokszC4C1sEvhRk29UO/HlTyUS8RtsJoMmsOc7kB56hOBic0ntEoJcqvS6CltnMmQKzOMHd/vsdKMm1kQaP6U2vUuhpSdvGa1caFAW4X71fB9jX7D0ccWv8B "Rust – Try It Online")

Comment: Right, not sure if an explicit function was required

Comment: You don't need the space at `&mut ""`

Comment: Um, that's weird. the official rust playground treats the `mut` in that case as a string prefix...

Answer (score 1):

## [PLIS](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/PLIS), 13 bytes

```
&R($0@@i@VfB)
```

Defines a function `R` which takes a sequence as its first and only parameter. The language implements strings as infinite sequences of `0`s preceded by the string itself. This program works for all sequences, strings included.

We define a function instead of using command line parameters because it is currently impossible to supply anything besides big integers through command line parameters. This would be 9 bytes if it were possible to supply, say, a string via command line (`$0@@i@VfB`).

```
print(R("umbrella"))        #=> mmrrllaa
print(R("Hello, World!"))   #=> eell,,WWrrdd
print(R("odd_length!"))     #=> dd__eegghh
```

### Explanation

After expanding shortnames, we have the following, equivalent code:

```
&R($0@@A000035@A004526)
&R(                   )      define a function R
       A000035               a(n) = n%2 ( 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 ... )
      @                      indices where true; ( 1 3 5 7 9 11 ... )
                             using shortnames, this is shorter than the equivalent 
                             A005408; compare CwB <=> @i
              @              index by
               A004526       non-negative integers repeated ( 0 0 1 1 2 2 ...)
                             this gives ( 1 1 3 3 5 5 7 7 9 9 ... )
   $0@                       index input by this sequence
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Dis](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Dis), 4 bytes

```
}}{{
```

[Offline interpreter on dis.web](https://tpaefawzen.github.io/dis.web/#source=%7D%7D%7B%7B&input_enc=utf-8&input=Hello%2C+World%21&output_enc=utf-8)

Easy for this kind of task.

A string of any bytes shall be given from standard input, and outputs to standard output.

### Explained

```
}    store odd-indexed byte to accumulator
     59048 is stored if EOF
 }   same for even-indexed byte
  {  output the accumulator
     halt if accumulator is 59048
   { same
     implicitly NOP until cell 59048
     loop back to cell 0
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Rockstar](https://codewithrockstar.com/), 70 bytes

```
listen to S
cut S
O's ""
while S
roll S
let O be+roll S*2 or ""

say O
```

[Try it](https://codewithrockstar.com/online) (Code will need to be pasted in)

Or, if we can output each pair of characters separately:

### 51 bytes

```
listen to S
cut S
while S
roll S
say roll S*2 or ""
```

Answer (score 1):

## *[Acc!!](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/tree/master/Acc!!)*, 46 bytes

```python
N
N
Count i while _/32 {
Write _
Write _
N
N
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xOTkr6/9@Py4/LOb80r0QhU6E8IzMnVSFe39hIoZorvCizBMiB0yCFtf//e6Tm5OTrKITnF@WkKAIA)

#### Explanation

```python
# Read two characters
N
N
# Loop while the most recent character code is 32 or greater
Count i while _/32 {
  # Write the most recent character twice
  Write _
  Write _
  # Read two more characters
  N
  N
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 11 bytes

```
ii::1+?!;oo
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/PzPTyspQ217ROj/////8lJT4nNS89JIMRQA)

Answer (score 0):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt), <s>6</s> 5 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py)

```
{ï¥∞*
```

-1 byte thanks to *@Neil*.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7/7/68PpDSx91zNP6/18pMSk5JTVNiUupNDepKDUnJxHIzMmHgbx0hZLUihKgGFAdkKzITk4BUh5Ahfk6CuH5RTkpikC@CxB7e4MkMoFEfkpKfE5qXnpJhqISAA)

**Explanation:**

```python
{      # Foreach over the characters of the (implicit) input-string:
 ï     #  Push the 0-based loop index
  ¥    #  Modulo-2 this index
   ∞   #  Double it
    *  #  Repeat the current character that many times (0 results in an empty string)
       # (after which the entire stack joined together is output implicitly)
```

Comment: `Æï¥∞*` seems to work for 5 bytes.

Comment: @Neil Ah, of course! Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

## [SNOBOL4 (CSNOBOL4)](http://www.snobol4.org/csnobol4/), <s>76</s> 74 bytes

```
	I =INPUT
N	I POS(X) LEN(1) (LEN(1) | '') . E @X =E E	:S(N)
	OUTPUT =I
END
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K87LT8rPMfn/n9NTwdbTLyA0hMsPyAzwD9aI0FTwcfXTMNRU0IDSNQrq6poKegquCg4RCrauCq6cVsEafppcnP6hIUCdQAO4XP1c/v/3SM3JyddRCM8vyklRBAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 74 bytes

```python
from functools import*
lambda s:reduce(tuple.__add__,zip(s[1::2],s[1::2]))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P60oP1chrTQvuSQ/P6dYITO3IL@oRIsrJzE3KSVRodiqKDWlNDlVo6S0ICdVLz4@MSUlPl6nKrNAozja0MrKKFYHSmtq/v8PAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Burlesque](https://github.com/FMNSSun/Burlesque), 6 bytes

```
2en)^^
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyotykktLixN/Z@TV/3fKDVPMy7uf21udHBATHRxxn@P1JycfB2F8PyinBRFrsSk5JTUNK7S3KQioHgiV04@DOSlK5SkVpSAVHBVZCencLlweXtzeWRy5aekxOek5qWXZCgCAA)

```
2en # Take every 2nd
)^^ # Map duplicate char
```

Answer (score 0):

## [J-uby](https://github.com/cyoce/J-uby), 21 bytes

```ruby
~:gsub&'\1\1'&/.(.)?/
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=TZBBCoJAFIZp6ymmgiywwl0E1iYi8AAuKsTxjaM5NjHOgG26SBsJOkKX6TQJNqOzecz3_bwf3vN9CRW-16-991Yyma8-jzUtFZ7YJ_fk2pPlYrqYbZet-w5mNyVLtD-OIhwDSUZnNEbeBmEMkCSWlqrAgjAWaV0UQjTfyAQY1-9KkSSV1EnDOaVSVpXV6-vKDK3yGDTOcwAjDk09d1DABYOhTpAGOk4QCNFL7v7WAN_Xed_v9mUaZpmBHCBk5EplaioaEhJCaZq2F6vrdv4A)

Answer (score 0):

## [C#](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 41 bytes

```cs
f=x=>x.Length<2?"":""+x[1]+x[1]+f(x[2..])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZJRa9swEMef40@h6clmrmB9rOuU0dCNpYOywPKQhiBLZ0dElpgkbwojnz09J9mok1I9yL7//e5O3J3wV8KLfeeVachs6wO0RfLaYvdWaxBBWePZFzDglDgjHpX5VSRCc@/Jk7ON4y35m4x84EEJ8tsqSb5zZVIfHEYtloS7xmc9MnrojLg96jk5fsekJiUxndbFvi5jOY7sEUwT1rfXd5TeUPoxLj4tj1edxsU1Y8tsXyTJRB1eyd32ImMAH/qk8IdcUicozYqk59hnKVPKKyGhpjmhVSVlXdOBt2srB1pzmtO2dQ7/@BDQ9t/BNgWIAcn/km2aEGKk5wWRqaqhGjdCorzZSDl0fMXyNidz67T8gASgnefzuXPn5AS9Q2U6RQmvYUKFolJD0Uq50ofm9zXQWAE0zXo9pE4FkntcEauBzZ0KgEsBp4mzbxanT58NtvMQNYN@o1Kc7QnASMFDiuNkU9hm/SneSHcsqfU7kWUZ2U@uO8hev@gHcHnIgOJut38B)

Answer (score 0):

## [Headass](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Headass), 8 bytes

```
{UN)UPP}
```

[Try It Online!](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJoZWFkYXNzIiwiIiwie1VOKVVQUH0iLCIiLCJcIkhcIlxuXCJlXCJcblwibFwiXG5cImxcIlxuXCJvXCJcblwiLFwiXG5cIiBcIlxuXCJXXCJcblwib1wiXG5cInJcIlxuXCJsXCJcblwiZFwiXG5cIiFcIiIsIiJd) - can take input as either list of characters or list of charcodes

###### Explanation:

```
{UN)UPP}  full program
{      }  loop
 U         discard nth input (1 indexed)
  N)       break out of loop if input is exhausted
    UPP    print n+1th input twice (1 indexed)
```