# Swap every two elements in the list every possible way

Tags: code-golf, permutations

Inspired by [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/237085/swap-every-two-elements-in-a-list) question.

### Challenge

Let `L` be a list of `n` distinct elements. Let `P` be the set of all (unordered) pairs of positions in P. Let `R` be a result of applying a pair-swap operation on `L` by every pair in `P` in any order.

Example:
`L = [1, 7, 8]`
`P = {(1, 2), (0, 1), (0, 2)}`
`L = [1, 7, 8] -> [1, 8, 7] -> [8, 1, 7] -> [7, 1, 8] = R`

Your task is to output every possible `R` (without multiplicity) in any order.

### Constraints

- `L` can have any length, including 0 and 1
- All elements of `L` are guaranteed to be distinct

### Examples

1. Input: `[1, 5]`
   Output: `[5, 1]`
2. Input: `[0, 1, 2, 3]`
   Output:
   `[3, 2, 1, 0]`
   `[1, 0, 3, 2]`
   `[2, 3, 0, 1]`
   `[3, 0, 2, 1]`
   `[1, 2, 0, 3]`
   `[1, 3, 2, 0]`
   `[2, 0, 1, 3]`
   `[2, 1, 3, 0]`
   `[0, 2, 3, 1]`
   `[3, 1, 0, 2]`
   `[0, 3, 1, 2]`
   `[0, 1, 2, 3]`
3. Input: `[150]`
   Output: `[150]`

### Rules

- this is `code-golf` challenge, so the shortest code wins
- [standard rules apply](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/default-for-code-golf-program-function-or-snippet/2422#2422) for your answer with [default I/O rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods/)
- [default Loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden.

Comment: I  suspect there's a parity argument of some sort...

Comment: It looks like these are always half the possible permutations, the odd-signed permutations when n modulo 4 is 1 or 2, and the even-signed permutations when it's 0 or 3. Related: [Parity of a Permutation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/75841/20260)

Comment: Alternatively, these are all even-signed permutations of the reverse of the list.

Comment: You should probably specify that \$P\$ is the set of all pairs of positions \$(i,j)\$ where \$i<j\$.

Comment: @JonathanAllan I've removed the checkmark. Could you explain what was wrong? As far as I can see, xnor's observation is valid. (And you can do the reverse either before or after listing all even permutations)

Comment: My observation about where the even permutations are in the list of permutations that Jelly's `Œ!` produces was incorrect.

Answer (score 6):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `koszul math.combinatorics`, <s>60</s> <s>52</s> 65 bytes

```
[ natural-sort [ reverse inversions even? ] filter-permutations ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYyxDoIwFEV3vuL@AAQ0LDo4GhcX40QYavPUBtri68NECd9eC07n5N7ce1daPMfr5XQ@7hDoNZLTFND58B17WCVPdMSO/l5ob2/GqbQxOmBgEvkMbJwgeBbjHthn2YQJFWrMiWWyDbarV3WZOMcG6WFk1efLCA2Y3sSBYNxC411AStwBLe6mF@J8ILajKFm7Nlo1oIg/)

Uses the following observation by @xnor: "Alternatively, these are all even-signed permutations of the reverse of the list." (Although I found it actually seems to be the reverse of each permutation of the list, not the reverse of the list.)

Comment: This approach doesn't seem to work when the original list is not sorted.

Comment: @xigoi Thanks. Fixed for +13 bytes.

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 13 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ŒcżU$Œ!y@ƒ€⁸Q
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASgA1/9qZWxsef//xZJjxbxVJMWSIXlAxpLigqzigbhR////WzAsMSwyLDNd)**

#### How?

Since the elements are guaranteed to be distinct we can swap pairs of elements rather than elements at pairs of indices and otherwise follow the description in the question.

```
ŒcżU$Œ!y@ƒ€⁸Q - Link: list of distinct integers, L
                                e.g. [1,7,8]
Œc            - pairs           [[1,7],[1,8],[7,8]]
    $         - last two links as a monad:
   U          -   upend         [[7,1],[8,1],[8,7]]
  ż           -   zip           [[[1,7],[7,1]],[[1,8],[8,1]],[[7,8],[8,7]]]
     Œ!       - all permutations
          €   - for each:
         ƒ ⁸  -   reduce by, starting with L:
        @     -     with swapped arguments:
       y      -       translate
            Q - deduplicate
```

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>17</s> 13 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
œʒRøãε`›`›}OÈ
```

-4 bytes thanks to [*@chunes*' corrected version](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/250428/52210) of [*@xnor*'s insight](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/250419/swap-every-two-elements-in-the-list-every-possible-way#comment558243_250419): "*These are all even-signed reversed permutations of the list.*"

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//6ORTk4IO7zi8@NzWhEcNu0C41v9wx///0QY6hjpGOsaxAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeWhlf@PTj41KejQuuLDOw4vPrc14VHDLhCu9T/c8b9W5390tKGOaaxOtIGOoY6RjjGQZWhqEBsLAA).

**Explanation:**

`` øãε`›`›}O `` is taken from [my 05AB1E answer in the related "*Parity of a Permutation*" challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/250434/52210) (which could alternatively be `øDδ›Æ0›˜O` for the same byte-count).

```python
œ           # Get all permutations of the (implicit) input-list
 ʒ          # Filter it by:
  R         #  Reverse the current permutation
   ø        #  Create pairs with the (implicit) input-list
    ã       #  Cartesian product of itself to get a list of all pairs of pairs
     ε      #  Map each pair of pairs to:
      `     #   Pop and push the pairs separately to the stack
       ›    #   Vectorized larger than check: [a,b] and [c,d] → [a>c,b>d]
        `   #   Pop and push the pairs separated to the stack again
         ›  #   Larger than check again: a>c and b>d → (a>c)>(b>d)
     }O     #  After the map: sum to get get the amount of truthy values
       È    #  Check if this sum is even
            # (after which the filtered list is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 13 bytes

```
2ḋṖƛ?$(nnṘĿ;U
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCIy4biL4bmWxps/JChubuG5mMS/O1UiLCIiLCJbMCwxLDIsM10iXQ==)

Port of Jonathan Allan's new Jelly answer.

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), 76 bytes

This is based on [xnor's insight](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/250419/swap-every-two-elements-in-the-list-every-possible-way#comment558242_250419).

```javascript
f=(a,k,...p)=>a.map((v,i)=>f(a.filter(_=>i--),i-~k,...p,v))+a||k&1||print(p)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bcrBCsIwDIDhu0@xkySYhk09CNK9iAwJw0KcSqilp@KrV2XH7fh//HfJ8h6jWnL5VGvwIDQRMxv6XvgpBpBJfxFAOOgj3SJcfa/OIan7zC9lxJ2UMm27UizqK4FhDXBpBzw3M@Dm39QthfZrRod1peOA9Qs)

Answer (score 0):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), <s>124</s> 121 bytes

```py
def p(a,k=0,t=0):
 if a[(i:=k):]:
  while a[i:]:c=[*a];c[k],c[i]=c[i],c[k];p(c,k+1,t+(i>k));i+=1
 elif~t%2:print(a[::-1])
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=VVFBbsMgEFSvfsUqUiVwSGW3jRo5pS_IDxAHgnFC7BiCsZpc-pFecmn_1L6m4LiNugfYGYZl2H3_tCe_Ne35_NH7arb4OpWqAosEqWlGPM1wkYCuQDCkC1rjggcMr1vdqMDpACVlqeBLyWpOJNOcxoVEuLRIknqaEz9F-qXGeKmnNE9ANbp687f3hXW69UiwopjlHF8MfN-oypk9aK-cN6bpQO-tcR7SJDrboGN0FOIAFDrlER6QC8iJdqNQo9qgubBdYINxssNQGQchAd2CdabspUeOOBz_pp93fJAPmkGh3L73wmvTdqgbH4whY8H0yP-IeEWQdbykC8lE_Pk69mAdM3EVHu5EWSLf20YhOdpzyveuhUOSxDKrWISxfJ5xAiwnMB_3JwKLmGYEAron8PAfEXjkw1gsWsXCl7Z2oWmqRCzdBJbj68GEUjoZu_079h8)

Answer (score 0):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>86</s> 36 bytes

```
⊞υ⟦⟧Ｆθ≔ΣＥυＥ⁻⎇﹪λ²⮌θθκ⁺κ⟦μ⟧υＥΦυ¬﹪κ²⭆¹ι
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=NY69CsIwEIB3n-LolEIKWhfBycWtUqxbyRBrbEPTRvMj-CwuDori4Pv4Nl78OTgO7r777k73quGm0lydz1fvtsnk9ci9bYinULJ4OthqA2Qfw8xaWfek8B3J-C6MQ8lk7y1ZCdNzcySZ3niliaKQxhSW4iCMFbhMIWSLmSvEW1R3LMag4PFEbmTvPta5VE6YIF9o99e1QRfYwiFYB25EQWJrerHryv7-vpVRclARe5blkAISKYUxY9_hGw) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
⊞υ⟦⟧Ｆθ≔ΣＥυＥ⁻⎇﹪λ²⮌θθκ⁺κ⟦μ⟧υ
```

Generate all the permutations of the input, alternating between even and odd permutations. This is based on my answer to [Hankel transform of an integer sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/260324/) but operates directly on the input instead of a range. This works because the elements in the input are guaranteed to be unique.

```
ＥΦυ¬﹪κ²⭆¹ι
```

Pretty-print only the even permutations.